# "Weekdays" used as an adverb

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, adverbs

I found a [sentence](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/weekday) in Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary:

> open weekdays from 9 a.m. to 6 p.m.
>
> The bookstore opens weekdays from 9 p.m. to 6 p.m. .

How do we understand the structure of this sentence? I know it means something is open on weekdays from 9 a.m. to 6 p.m.

Comment: What else is there to understand?

Comment: @J.R. Sorry, I learn English as a second language. I don't understand the sentence pattern. Why `weekdays` can be used here, and can you give me another similar example?

Comment: No need to apologize for having English as a second language. I just wondered, if you realize it means something is open on Mon thru Fri from 9 until 6, what are you asking about?  At least now we understand your question has to do with the sentence structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your reference, you can see that the word "weekdays" can be used either as a Noun (which you normally know) or as an Adverb:

> The centre is open on weekdays. (Noun)
>
> The centre is open weekdays. (Adverb)

In the second example, the adverb is describing the verb. So it doesn't need a preposition anymore to connect to the rest of the sentence.

---

In addition, we sometimes drop "*on*" before days in spoken English.

For example:

> I work out Monday mornings.
>
> See you Friday!

Comment: -1 I don't think you can meaningfully say *weekdays* is an "adverb". What about my local shop, which is open Christmas morning until 11:30? Would you defend "Christmas morning [until 11:30]" as an adverb? I certainly wouldn't. It's just a qualifying noun, with the word "on" elided.

Comment: @Fumble Fingers, check out the OP's source above. The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary specifically mentions that "weekdays" CAN be an adverb

Comment: In that case I think The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary is *wrong*. I will ask the community.

Comment: I don't suppose I'm going to win a shootout with OALD, but [here's the question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/what-exactly-is-an-adverb) anyway.

Comment: Just saw it. Yes, I think that would do the job

Comment: @FumbleFingers, how right you were!

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the full sentence is "open **on** weekdays from 9 a.m. to 6 p.m.", and the "on" was dropped somewhere along the way. So "weekdays" here isn't actually used as an adverb, it just seems that way.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it means "open from Monday till Friday, but not Saturday or Sunday".  So "weekdays" is an adverb, because it qualifies "open".

Comment: `This store opens weekdays from 9 a.m. to 6 p.m.` Is this sentence right? The adverb `weekdays` is used to describe the verb `open`, right?

Comment: @UniMouS why is so important for you to know whether weekdays is adverb or not?

Comment: @Carlo_R. Perhaps because I do not quite understand why this sentence can be written like this, and I try to get a better understanding of this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a sentence, it's a sentence fragment.  You'd normally hear it in a larger context, such as:

> *That grocery store is only open weekdays from 9 to 6*.

You might see that “abbreviated” form on a storefront sign, though.

Comment: @CoolElf has explained it rather well in his answer.