# What exactly is an "adverb"?

Tags: grammar, terminology, adverbs

From comments to [“Weekdays” used as an adverb"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75477/weekdays-used-as-an-adverb), I learn that The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary says ["open weekdays from 9 a.m. to 6 p.m."](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/weekdays?q=weekdays), shows the word *weekdays* is an adverb.

It seems to me that in *"We open **weekdays** at 7 a.m."*, and *"We open **tomorrow** at 7 a.m."* both *weekdays* and *tomorrow* are the same "part of speech" - and again in *"I'll go **tomorrow**"*.

I will happily describe words like *happily* and *quickly* as adverbs - for example...

> *"I'll go **quickly**"*, and by extension *"I'll go **quickly and quietly**"*.

On the other hand...

> *"I'll go **tomorrow**"* can't be extended to *"I'll go **tomorrow and quietly**"*.

Am I being thick, or is OALD spouting nonsense?

Comment: Aren’t adverbs all the leftovers in POS assignments when they couldn’t figure out what else to call the remainders? :) BTW, I don’t see what’s wrong with “I’ll go tomorrow — and quietly,” apart from the manifest lack of parallelism. That is, the grammar is ok but the style is a little offputting, which may be an intended effect I suppose. When you use *and* you are expecting them all of the same class, like “quickly, calmly, and quietly” rather than like “quickly, calmly, and often”. The former just feels better stylistically, but the latter is not wrong. But `s/often/weekdays/` and hmm . . .

Comment: @tchrist: Even with the hyphen I think it's a little odd. But my point is you can run *quickly and quietly* together, and I think that's because they're the same "part of speech". Correspondingly, I think *tomorrow and quietly* doesn't work because they're *not* the same part of speech. I just want to know *why*, and what terminological distinction can clarify that for me, because "adverb" seems like a pretty useless term if that's all we've got.

Comment: This was asked moments ago: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75477/weekdays-used-as-an-adverb

Comment: Isn't this either Gen Ref, or since you disagree with one particular Ref, it is Not Constructive, a call to discussion. If not, then what exactly is the question? I think this is an interesting question, but I feel you'd vote to close it pretty quickly if it weren't your own.

Comment: It's true. A part of EL&U would've easily considered dismissing a question like this if it had come from a non-native speaker or a newbie

Comment: @FumbleFingers That’s not a hyphen; it’s a dash.  The key difference is that hyphens join while dashes separate. A long-winded phrase has a hyphen — but this does not. And a Chicago–Philadelphia flight (or game) has a dash, but a Chicago-Philly fusion has a hyphen. See the difference?

Comment: @Mitch But it has the possibility of **an** answer, which I believe suffices. It’s probably not GenRef unless you’re a linguist of one sort or another.

Comment: @Mitch, Cool Elf: I agree that something as basic as "what is an adverb" ought to be General Reference. But OALD citing *weekdays* as an adverb makes me think that huge numbers of words are therefore also "adverbs". Whilst I do now realise that *tomorrow and quietly* is probably irrelevant, I'm still having trouble getting my head around the idea that just because I can say *"I'll call you Monday"*, it suddenly becomes meaningful to say that *Monday* is an adverb.

Comment: "Monday" is still a Noun according to OALD, although we normally leave out the preposition in spoken English:  http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/monday

Comment: It seems a bit of a cop-out to imply that somehow *Monday* isn't classified as an adverb simply because we *could* have preceded it by *"on"*. That argument surely applies equally well to *"weekdays"* in the original example.

Comment: I guess what it comes down to is there are nouns and there are adverbs, and we shouldn't remember all nouns as adverbs just because they have the option of shrugging off their prepositions. I don't really see OALD doing that

Comment: @Cool Elf: My gut feel is that probably not *all* nouns can be used as adverbs. For example, how could you achieve that with *"universe"*?

Comment: Precisely. There are just those long-time adverbs like home, yesterday, tomorrow, abroad, overseas, upstairs, downstairs etc.

Comment: The discussion so far leads me to believe tchrist's first comment and an agreeing channeling of what I think John Lawler will say, that POS is kinda vague and adverb is the vaguest catch-all of them all. Anyway, a 'word' isn't always necessarily exactly one part of speech: _Monday_ may 'be' a proper noun sometimes, bu act like an adverb at others.

Comment: @Mitch Notice how there’s an `acp` NUPOS tag, which is a catch-all tag standing for “adverb/conjunction/particle/preposition”.

Comment: Haven't read all the answers, but I can see no reason at all why you can't say 'I'll go tomorrow and quietly.'

Comment: @Barrie England: It was a bad example, illustrating a bit of wrong-headed thinking on my part. In the end my problem was simply that I'd confused *[word] = adverb* with *[word] **in some specific context** = adverb (or "is used adverbially")* But tchrist's observation about ***some** adverbs that can be inflected to give superlatives* was a very useful concept for me in this context. I'm happier now to just think of *those* as archetypal adverbs in almost any context. Most others are simply words that can function adverbially.

Comment: ...anyway, the question has obviously struck a chord, so I'm glad it didn't get closed as General Reference in the first 10 minutes!

Comment: I've always thought of *adverb* (or, more precisely, *adverbial*) as a catch all term for any word that modifies a whole clause / sentence.

Comment: @Pitarou: I never had a problem understanding the concept of "adverbial function". The key point (for me at least) is that the attribute **adverb** accrues to a word (or expression) *in some particular context*, rather than to the word or expression "in isolation".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not just adverbs!  A word's class and a word's function in a sentence are related, but distinct.  Just like written English and spoken English.  A significant proportion of the questions on EL&U come from people confused because they haven't yet grasped this.

Comment: @Barrie England: One would say _I'll go quietly tomorrow_ or _I'll go tomorrow - quietly_. Adverbs of different 'conceptual notion' are not coordinated: He read it slowly and thoroughly. (manner + manner) / He read it thoroughly yesterday. (manner;temporal) / *He read it thoroughly and yesterday. (manner + temporal) / He will come here tomorrow. (directional;temporal) / *He will come here and tomorrow. (directional + temporal) *He often and greatly enjoyed it (frequency + degree) / He often enjoyed it greatly. (frequency;degree)

Comment: We must allow for the possibility of zeugma.

Comment: That's just giving a name to usually unacceptable double constructions - like, I'd say, 'I'll go tomorrow and quietly.' _Why_ adverbs of different conceptual notion form nonstandard double constructions (and I can't think of any exceptions at the moment) is a different matter.

Comment: Main question is awesome, but a ***conjunction*** implies a ***junction***. The *junction* of *tomorrow* and *quietly* is obscure at best, so the use of *and* to join them is awkward even if it is "correct". *I'll go quietly tomorrow*, (or *I'll go tomorrow quietly*) is the intuitive construction; so the *and* simply **distracts from the meaning** of the sentence by implying a connection that does not really exist. It's like coon dogs chasing mouse turds:)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Such a pity that such a straightforwardly correct intuition, backed up by evidence and vetted grammar sources has lead you to being bamboozled by asking a question here and then to you stamping on any other question that asks the same kind of thing :(  - I've voted top close on a point of principle [actually was dithering but can't retract it - but can't think of a reason why to do so either]

Comment: @Araucaria: Three other people have also voted to close this question, so I suppose there's a good chance one more will finish it off. That would be quite an interesting situation, given there are well over 100 net upvotes on this page. Most of the votes are for "Too Broad", which strikes me as somewhat inscrutable given the *original* closevotes were all "General Reference". In a way, I almost hope it *does* get closed, because that would justify me asking for a review on Meta (and maybe someone would enlighten me as to what "Too Broad" means here).

Comment: @FumbleFingers The reason it's too broad is this: many questions about noun versus adverb, preposition versus adverb, adjective versus adverb are getting close votes, or near close votes because of this post - sometimes from you. This question is stifling the ability of other users to ask sensible straightforward questions about grammar here. Worse than that the question hasn't been answered. If this were not happening I wouldn't be bothered - but it is. Now previously, my thinking was to leave alone - because, after all, it has a lot of upvotes, depsite the fact that the top answer ...

Comment: ... is just plain misleading. However, in one of your comments that I read yesterday, you were saying to another user that the number of votes should *not* have a bearing on whether a specific post was closed or not. So I changed my mind - after some deliberation. I don't believe this question is answerable any more properly on this site, because the amount of really bad answers here would require too lengthy a post to address all the issues. Even if anyone ever got round to reading it.

Comment: @Araucaria: If you think tchrist's answer is "misleading", or that [JSBձոգչ](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/48/jsb%D5%B1%D5%B8%D5%A3%D5%B9) was misguided when he gave it one of the highest bounties ever awarded on ELU, then by all means post an alternative for others to vote on. I found the answer more than sufficient for my needs, and I'm in no doubt that those two guys both know *far* more about such matters than I do.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As I said, it's now too broad. To be able to address the issues raised by the other posts there it would have to cover the following questions i) what is a part of speech ii) what is a function iii) why can't a part of speech have a function iv) why can't a function be a POS v) what is a noun vi) what is a preposition vii) what is an adverb. None of those are small posts, and 7 is way too much. I ain't gonna do no nutter answer post to resolve that problem when no-ones going to read it anyhow. They wouldn't read it because a) it'd be too long b) it'd be too long c) too long :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers OK, to see why *weekdays* is [a noun and not an adverb, see here!](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229194/how-can-i-prove-a-word-is-a-noun/229888#229888) :)

Comment: @Araucaria: I suspect your linked answer might be a bit counterproductive for me! :) Bear in mind I only asked this question because I was initially taken aback by the [Oxford Advanced American Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/weekday) entry cited in the first question linked to by mine here (where OAAD says ***weekdays** ADVERB*, e.g. *open weekdays from 9am to 6pm)*. So far as I'm concerned, my confusion was simply because I hadn't taken on board that such categorisations apply to *usage **in context***. They're not inherent attributes of "words".

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's the point really. If you take a word to be a series of letters, or series of sounds then you can say things like that. But if you agree that a *cry* meaning a shout and *cry* meaning to weep are different words, different lexemes, then that no longer is true. Verbs and nouns have inherent properties as John Lawler says. These do not change when they are used in a different syntactic relation. They remain the same. So the verb *cry* remains a verb even when used as a subject. Nouns remains nouns even when used as adjuncts (read adverbials). To understand NUPOS ...

Comment: @FumbleFingers ... tagging you really need to know what it's designed for. It was specifically designed to allow people who have no knowledge of grammar outside what they teach you at early secondary school to mine data for the social sciences. So they don't use function labels - they assume you won't know them. They use secondary school analogies instead. They also mine stuff that isn't parts of speech - for example 3rd person singular is not a part of speech. NUPOS is useful for what it's meant to do. But grammarish it aint! And *weekdays* is *NEVER*, ever an adverb. In any context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I still think you should give it a careful read! What have you got to loose? :)

Comment: @Araucaria: ***Loose**???* I could lose my somewhat shaky grip on *spelling, for a start! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Just seeing if you're awake ;) (I'm obviously not!!)

Comment: @Araucaria: Awake, but just about to go AFK for a "happy hour" (I'm in the happy position of not having yet watched last week's episode of [*Better Call Saul*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3032476/), so I'm going to watch it now. Then - *Yippee!!!!* - there'll be another one tomorrow! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The theory of adverbs (and of Conjunction Reduction) given by McCawley in **The Syntactic Phenomena of English** explains why you can't get your example

```
*"I'll go tomorrow and quietly."
```

It would have to come by Conjunction Reduction from

```
[[I'll go] tomorrow] and I'll [[go] quietly]
```

but Conjunction Reduction requires the two constituents to be conjoined to occupy the same place in the original conjoined structures.  That is not the case here, as I've indicated with the brackets -- "tomorrow" is a sentence modifier, but the manner adverb "quietly" is a V' modifier.

Comment: Thanks to John Lawler, I actually have the mighty tome! I didn't when I raised this Q, but I'm not sure I would have recognised the answer to  my question here even if I *had* read it cover to cover before asking. Your text makes it crystal clear, ty. Anyway, I'm sure you mean *The Syntactic **Phenomena** of English* - I don't think he did another one with such a similar title.

Answer (score 78):

Most anything that answers a “when” question can be roped into service as an adverb, even if it is normally considered a noun or a prepositional phrase.

> Q: When are you going?
>
> A: Immediately.
> A: Soon.
> A: Now.
> A: In a while.
> A: After I’m done eating.
> A: Tomorrow.
> A: Next week.
> A: Friday.
> A: Never.

All these answers are acting like adverbs in this context. But are they really adverbs? What about nouns like *tomorrow* or *next Tuesday*?  Are those adverbs, too?

The simple answer is “Yes.”

A better answer is “Well sure, sorta.”

But the best is answer is “What’s an adverb?”

And thereon hangs a much longer tale.

---

The problem is, asking whether something is an adverb is a devilishly loaded question. It assumes that there is such a thing as a “real adverb”, which as it turns out isn’t a reasonable assumption at all. There are just words, and words do as they please — meaning, they do as their speakers please. <sub><sup>(Yes, Humpty-Dumpty was right after all. :)</sup></sub>

Sometimes they happen to do jobs we call *adverbial*, like answering “when” questions. So, for a short-hand, we call them *adverbs* there, using a classic part of speech tag known to scholars and school children alike.

Understand that part-of-speech (POS) tags are just an invention. They are sometimes a useful invention, true, but there are not really a necessary one.  That’s because words in English are free to fall into whatever slot they want to, to do the needed job. That’s why we end up having so many “*this* as *that*” type tags when doing good POS assignment in natural language work on a computer.

One thing that occurs to me is that these “noun-adverbs” (meaning nouns doing an adverbial job) do not appear to admit normal adverbial inflections into the comparative and superlative degrees.  Go back to the list of `A: ...` adverbial answers above and try to inflect them by degree. Sure, you can do something *sooner*, so that one inflects.  But some do not. You are free to “do something tomorrow”, but you may not “do it *more tomorrow”.

Perhaps it bothers you that we have words doing one of the (many) duties of adverbs by answering temporal questions, but which refuse to be roped into another customary adverbial duty, inflections according to degree. Is that perhaps the origin of the question? If so, then the problem is really that we need more distinct parts of speech than the traditional ones.

One problem with assigning POS tags to English words is that this is something of an artificial distinction, the product of artifice alone. All that matters is how a word is used, and even then the granularity of your tag-set varies considerably. In short, it just depends how you slice it.

You will find that the POS tag-sets used by various reference works vary a bit, sometimes a good bit. Even the OED changed a little in how it assigns parts of speech to senses between v2 and v3. For example, many words once marked as a prefix or suffix in the OED2 are now held to be combining forms.

This is especially noticeable when doing syntactic analysis for natural language processing. The parser will make POS assignments to each word in the sentence analysed, and you have to know what each POS tag means.

A particularly common set of POS tags is the Penn Treebank tags. Someone who comes from the school that admits only the seven “classic” parts of speech (<sup><sub>NOUN, PRONOUN, VERB, ADJECTIVE, ADVERB, PREPOSITION, CONJUNCTION</sub></sup>) may find [Penn’s 36 POS tags](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html) to be elaborate and useful.  But I am not especially fond of them, because they conflate many things that are useful to distinguish in a parse. I prefer [the NUPOS tagset](http://morphadorner.northwestern.edu/morphadorner/documentation/nupos/), which is a much, much richer tag-set.

If you look at the NUPOS tags for adverbs, you will find that they have a category of adverb called a *noun-adverb*, meaning a noun used in a slot expecting an adverb, analogously to how a *noun-adjective* is a noun used in a slot expecting an adjective.

This isn’t anything fancy, and is indeed the very phenomenon we’re discussing here.  When we say “Go home”, we find that we are using *home*, a word normally thought of as a noun, as an adverb.  That’s because we are indicating where to go, and where is an adverbial application. If you like fancy words, *locatives* are always adverbs. <sup><sub>(And *home* is a very good example of a locative, and a very popular one historically just as it is today.  That’s why the noun for *home* in Latin, [*domus*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/domus#Declension), preserved a vestigial locative form, *domī*, but lost almost all the other distinct locative inflexions for the rest of its nouns.)</sub></sup>

Where some classical grammars use 7 POS tags and Penn uses 36 of them, NUPOS uses 17 major word classes:

| Word Class |
| --- |
| adjective |
| adv/conj/pcl/prep |
| adverb |
| conjunction |
| determiner |
| foreign word |
| interjection |
| negative |
| noun |
| numeral |
| preposition |
| pronoun |
| punctuation |
| symbol |
| undetermined |
| verb |
| *wh*-word |

But those 17 are further split up into a set of 34, including things like this:

| Name | Description | Major Class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| acp | adverb/conjunction/particle/preposition | adv/conj/pcl/prep |
| an | adverb/noun | noun |
| av | adverb | adverb |
| cc | coordinating conjunction | conjunction |
| crq | wh-word | wh-word |
| cs | subordinating conjunction | conjunction |
| d | determiner | determiner |
| dt | article | determiner |

Even there, we can see that here there is such a thing as an *adverb/noun*, which belongs to the major class of noun. But there’s more than one way to skin a cat, which is why NUPOS goes much farther, dividing up those 34 major classes into 241 different final POS tags. Here for example are the adverbial NUPOS tags, with illustrative examples:

| Tag | Explanation | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a-acp | acp word as adverb | *I have not seen him since* |
| av | adverb | *soon* |
| av-an | noun-adverb as adverb | *go home* |
| av-c | comparative adverb | *sooner, rather* |
| avc-jn | comparative adj/noun as adverb | *deeper* |
| av-d | determiner/adverb as adverb | *more slowly* |
| av-dc | comparative determiner/adverb as adverb | *can lesser hide his love* |
| av-ds | superlative determiner as adverb | *most often* |
| av-dx | negative determiner as adverb | *no more* |
| av-j | adjective as adverb | *quickly* |
| av-jc | comparative adjective as adverb | *he fared worse* |
| av-jn | adj/noun as adverb | *duly, right honourable* |
| av-js | superlative adjective as adverb | *in you it best lies* |
| av-n1 | noun as adverb | *had been cannibally given* |
| av-s | superlative adverb | *soonest* |
| j-av | adverb as adjective | *the then king* |
| n1-an | noun-adverb as singular noun | *my home* |
| n1-j | adjective as singular noun | *a good* |
| n2-an | noun-adverb as plural noun | *all our yesterdays* |
| n2-av | adverb as plural noun | *and are etcecteras not things?* |
| n2-dx | determiner/adverb negative as plural noun | *yeas and honest noes* |
| ng1-an | noun-adverb in singular possessive use | *Tomorrow’s vengeance* |
| uh-av | adverb as interjection | *Well!* |

Yup, that’s a lot of POS tags.  But it is useful for people doing NLP to have these nuanced distinctions. It may be useful in other work, too.

So which of those are adverbs? Hard question. Facile answer is that those beginning with *av** are. Oh and *dx*. Maybe some others, too.

See the problem? We’re categorizing things according to their job in the actual phrase, and words in English are super-flexible in their job-duties, much more so than a dictionary’s simple-minded part-of-speech listing suggests.

Comment: It's a bit long, but this answer does it for me. Specifically because although you "sorta" refer to *"home"*, say, as an "adverb", I can't help noticing that you often use expressions like *noun-adverb, used an adverb, adverbially, etc. In the end, classifications such as *noun, verb, adverb, etc.* don't always apply very well to "words" considered "in isolation". It makes more sense to say the classification applies to a word *in the context of some specific usage*. I'm now happy that *"Monday" can be used adverbially*, even though I'd rather not say *"Monday" is therefore an adverb*.

Comment: This is very informative! Looking at the tags in the Penn Treebank, why does "_to_" get a dedicated tag?

Comment: @coleopterist *To* gets a dedicated tag for when you have something like “I love to eat.”  You cannot call *to* a preposition there, nor is it a verb, either.  It’s just *to*.

Comment: @tchrist I see. Cheers :)

Comment: The fact that you've got *can be roped into service as an adverb* in your very first sentence is the deciding factor for me, so I'm accepting this answer. I must admit I feel a bit sheepish about having asked the question in the first place, but I've got it clear in my mind now, thanks!

Comment: When I read the beginning, my brain was telling me the Adverb is a Lie. Until I carried on reading. Great answer, learned a lot from reading it. Thanks!

Comment: In "go home", "home" would not be a locative but an accusative, IMS.

Comment: """When we say “Go home”, we find that we are using home, a word normally thought of as a noun, as an adverb.""" - I always thought of this as an object to an unacknowledged transitive form of "go".

Comment: LOL! All that to say, **A word is an *adverb* if it's *used* as an adverb**. This answer is academically stimulating, but practically dissatisfying--except for a narrow application for computer tagging. For communication purposes, it's easy as pie to find the omitted preposition that forms the implied prepositional phrase, which confers adverbial function onto the noun. We open ***on*** Wednesdays. We arrive ***to*** + morrow / ***to*** + night. Any noun with *locative* or *temporal*  implications naturally lends itself to adverbial use when it satisfies an adverbial query. Let's go home.

Answer (score 10):

Cool Elf is right: those are all adverbs, because they modify verbs, adjectives, or other adverbs. That is not to say that there aren't different *kinds* of adverbs; I believe modern Anglo-Saxon syntacticians even use different words for them. But this is the meaning of the word "adverb" as it is commonly used.

As to *tomorrow*, your example is a just a regular semantic syllepsis, which proves nothing:

> I hit the ball and my head.

This doesn't mean that *ball* and *head* aren't both nouns. It just sounds odd because the verb *hit* is used in two slightly different ways.

Comment: I think this answer is correct. English has several different classes of adverbs, and they can't be used in parallelism. Consider "he spoke to her rarely and imploringly." They're both clearly adverbs, but they don't work together.

Comment: I suppose I can't disagree with this - and I certainly recognise now that my *tomorrow and quietly* was pointlessly confusing (but I thought and wrote it, so I'll let it stand). But in the final analysis I'm more comfortable with the answers from Carlo_R. and tchrist, which don't explicitly defend the idea of calling "the word" *weekdays* an adverb. Rather, they say that *such words can be used adverbially*, which makes much more sense to me.

Comment: Another oddity of noun-adverbs / adverb-nouns, beyond not being subject to normal adverbial comparative and superlative inflexions, is that they are very hard to rope into accepting an article, whether definite or indefinite. You really can’t get away with *∗the tomorrow*, *∗this yesterday*, or *∗a yesterday* unless you strain really hard at it. And yet they readily accept plural and/or possessive/genitive inflexions just fine, as in “all our yesterdays” and “yesterday’s children” (which NUPOS respectively indicates using its `n2-an` and `ng1-an` tags).

Answer (score 5):

The best way to remember how an adverb works is very simple: it describes **how** something is done or **where** or **when**, the verb is the action, the adverb describes the action.

The sign is a truncated form of a sentence; this is common. The original complete sentence more likely would have been:

**"We are open on weekdays from 9 am to 6 pm."**

"*We*" is the subject, a pronoun used to replace the owners of the store, who are saying something to us. "*Are*" is the action, the verb. "*Open*" describes "*We"*, and thus is an adjective. The rest of the sentence is a complex prepositional phrase, at least if you are still learning. It describes how or when something is being done, so it works as an adverb.

The other thing to remember is that much less commonly an adverb describes and adjective (and consequently it **NEVER** describes a noun, such as the subject or object of a sentence.) It modifies the adjective. It tells us to what degree, how much, what kind of adjective.

**The night was surreally beautiful and still.**

**I am very sick today and cannot come to work.**

Remember these rules and you shall never fail to understand. Other than that, a note: Speakers of American English use something called the adverbial genitive more often than the rest of the English speaking world; American English received a large amount of its vocabulary and structure from British English as it was spoken from 1620-1730.  The adverbial genitive was more common in England at the time but rarely is used anymore by comparison.  So, if an American says "**I don't schedule meetings Fridays**"  he is correct, but using an older form that might not work in a British dialect.

Comment: Hi Mary - welcome to ELU. I've upvoted your answer because it's all true, and clearly expressed. But as you may have realised from my other comments on this page, my problem wasn't *really* about how to identify contexts where a word *"works as an adverb"*. It was my mistaken idea that *words themselves* can always be classified as one POS or another. In many cases they can't - it all depends on the context in which they're used.

Comment: You say that adverbs never describe a noun. The only way that can be true requires a tortured, self-referential, and circular definition.  Consider the NP “the then king”, as I gave in my own answer.  Most taggers will call that *then* an adverb, such as `RB` in Penn tags. NUPOS tags allow for `j-rb`, meaning an adverb *used* as an adjective, which is indeed what is occurring.

Comment: I am letting it stand because the way you have it is nowhere near as common as what I wrote originally, and teaching your construction to people who are just learning will only confuse them. "Then"as a word can be placed in a sentence dozens of ways. They need to learn that first before they see its use otherwise. Otherwise, in this case I see it as a change in part of speech, becoming a synonym for past, similar to how jump the verb becomes a noun, as one is the action and the other is the act.

Comment: **Nominal** use: *Mondays are the toughest days,* and also *Monday’s child is fair of face.* Adverbial use: *Mondays I always get up late,* or also *We have a meeting Monday.*  Adjectival use: *Monday morning meetings are always sleepy ones.*  Verbal use: *Don’t just good morning me and walk off!*

Comment: @tchrist :I've only just found this thread! I don't like the classification of words like 'then' (as in your example), 'former',  'alleged', 'mere', 'fake' (as in 'a fake gun') as true adjectives at all - though I've seen them classed as 'non-semantically-predicative adjectives'. They seem, to me, to comment on the classification, some aspect of the classification, or the time-reference of the associated noun's referent rather than any attribute. I'd say they have almost a determiner-with-semantic-content function. And any connection with adverbialness has been lost in the mists of ellipsis.

Comment: There is an article on these tricky words at http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=23523

Answer (score 2):

> An adverbial phrase (AdvP) is a linguistic term for a group of two or more words operating adverbially, when viewed in terms of their syntactic function.
>
> Compare the following sentences:
>
> - I'll go to bed soon.
> - I'll go to bed in an hour.
> - I'll go to bed when I've finished my book.
>
> In the first, soon is an adverb (as distinct from a noun or verb), and it is an adverbial (as distinct from a subject or object). Clearly, in the second sentence, in an hour has the same syntactic function, though it does not contain an adverb; therefore, a prepositional phrase consisting of a preposition and a noun (preceded by its article) can function as an adverbial and is called an adverbial phrase. In the third sentence, we see a whole clause functioning as an adverbial; it is termed an adverbial clause.

So, 'weekdays' is an adverb for the same (syntactic) reason 'soon' is an adverb in the above example.

Reference: Wikipedia, *[Adverbial phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_phrase)*

Answer (score 2):

As two professional linguists David Ward and John Lawler, said last week and the week before that, respectively, "**Part of speech (POS) is not important: function is important**". A nominal adjective is always a noun, even when it functions as an adjective. *Tomorrow* functions very well and most often as a noun and an adverb of time. I don't know which POS of speech it is. The dictionary calls it both a noun and an adverb based on its function, not its POS.

> He's a real **nowhere** man,
>   Sitting in his **Nowhere** Land,
>   Making all his **nowhere** plans
>   for nobody.

***Nowhere*** is an adjective in the first and third lines in these Beatles lyrics, a noun (function: nominal adjective) in the second line, and a locative adverb in the sentence "*I have **nowhere** to go*". POS doesn't matter: function matters.

"*I'll see you Monday*" is merely an elided sentence because grammatically, according to Chomsky, the underlying structure is "*I'll see you **on** Monday*", so the preposition in front of the proper noun **Monday** is missing. However, because there's no preposition and it has the same structure as "*I'll see you **soon***", it seems to function as an adverb of time. Does the underlying structure really exist? Does it really matter? It's both a terminological question and a theoretical question. What linguistic theory or paradigm are we using to parse the sentence: structural, functional, generative, cognitive, or some other? I don't know how many there are, but whatever one's answer, one has put oneself into a box that restricts and, therefore, biases one's analysis.

If we don't all agree to the same definitions and values for the terms we use when describing language, then how can we meaningfully discuss it?

Comment: I don't see why you say *Sitting in his **Nowhere** Land* uses *"nowhere"* any differently to the lines before and after. They all look like "adjectives" to me, modifying *man, Land, plans* respectively. If it were otherwise, wouldn't that constitute a form of *syllepsis*, and wouldn't that therefore cause the average listener/reader to stumble a bit on having to deal with the switch in function?

Comment: In the 2nd line, _Nowhere_ is a proper noun, the name of the land in which he's sitting: capital "N". It's a nominal adjective. That's its function. The tyrannical dictionary says "nowhere"'s an adjective & an adverb, depending on how it's used. Strictly terminological. Not a matter of substance. POS is unimportant. Function is important. It's not syllepsis. All these usages are commonplace in English. What's the diff between a **New York strip steak** & a **new york strip steak**? None, but w/o the caps, "new york" isn't the proper name of NYC. In all the lines, "nowhere" functions as an ADJ.

Comment: Nah. I don't buy that. He could have just as easily been sitting in [his **fantasy** land](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22his+fantasy+land%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and I'm not about to be convinced that would mean *a land called "Fantasy"*. Also note that it's a *song*, so you can pretty much ignore any possible capitalisation.

Comment: Regardless of the POS. It isn't used any differently in those three lines: the function is the same, but the POS is different. Gotta go to bed now. Just after midnight here. More tomorrow. Maybe we'll have to take this to chat.

Comment: If it had been written as "sitting in his nowhere land", I'd have to call "nowhere" and ADV that functions as an ADJ. This is just theoretical linguistics. Remember what David Ward said about tenses in English: if the sentence talks about the future, then the tense of the sentence, not the verb, is future tense. John Lawler & I both said, OTOH, that there are only two tenses in English, past & present. Ward doesn't buy that. I can't adjudicate this discrepancy: they're professional linguists. I'm just an amateur. The functional argument's persuasive to me. I'm not a total dogmat. G'nite. :-)

Comment: One of my favourite "Lawlerisms" (I've collected quite a few lately!) is [the trick is to remember that real language is spoken, while written language is technology](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/68477/2637). Which is my prime motivation for saying capitalisation in Lennon's lyrics is effectively irrelevant if it conflicts with other information.

Comment: I don't see how the two statements: (1) 'A nominal adjective is always a noun, even when it functions as an adjective' (2) 'POS doesn't matter: function matters' can seriously be uttered in the same breath.

Answer (score 0):

From our old grammar textbooks, adverbs are words that describe verbs, adjectives, and other adverbs.

Ex.

> He runs **fast**.
>
> He is **incredibly** fast.
>
> He did **incredibly** well.

I didn't quite get what you mean by citing the word "*tomorrow*." "Tomorrow" has always been a prototypical adverb in that it describes verbs by expressing time. For the same reason, it doesn't use any prepositions before it as well.

---

As for "weekdays," it has often been a noun for me too. But I suppose if "[weekends](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weekends)" can be an adverb, why not "weekdays"?

Comment: I’ve heard that some UK speakers rankle at the use of days of the week as unprepositioned *when*-adverbs. To me, it makes no difference to say “I don’t work Sunday/Sundays/weekdays/weekends,” but not everyone speaks as I do. Perhaps contrast  American “I’ll see you Monday then” with the ungrammatical “I’ll see you *January then ” to get a feel for their discomfort.

Comment: I cited *tomorrow* because it seems to me it functions the same as *weekdays* in my examples, and it made it easier to construct my final example *"*I'll go tomorrow and quietly"*, which to my mind shows that *tomorrow* doesn't work the same as *quickly*.

Comment: On the contrary for me, "tomorrow" fits perfectly well as an adverb in that slot and works in almost the same way as "quietly"

Comment: @tchrist: There's nothing wrong with "I'll see you next January". So this leads us to the rather unfortunate conclusion that "January" is not an adverb, but "next January" is.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A better example that we’re not dealing with the same class of word here is that while you can go *more quietly* or even *sooner*, you cannot go *∗more tomorrow* or *∗more Tuesday*. That’s because noun-adverbs are not so amenable to being inflected according to degree as certain others sorts of adverbs are. See my longer answer.

Comment: Cool Elf - your *fits perfectly well as an adverb **in that slot*** exactly resolves my issue! At the time of writing the question I was still thinking in terms of "a word" being somehow independent of the contexts in which it's actually used. But as @Peter Shor so incisively points out, this can lead to some *rather unfortunate conclusions*.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I don't know if tchrist is right that *some UK speakers* don't like *"I'll see you Monday"* any more than some Americans might. It's fine by me. In fact, I don't really think I have a problem with saying *"I'll see you guys January"* as I leave office on Christmas Eve. And I'm certainly okay with *"I'll see you next summer"*, but *"I'll see you summer"* is dead in the water. Classification of words *as disembodied words, out of context* simply doesn't work in many cases.

Comment: Adverbs can also describe prepositions; either that, or we can inflect prepositions into comparative and superlative degrees. “Are you still **with John**? I’m even **more with him** that I’ve ever been. I’m **most with him** at nights.” Somehow grammar books seem to miss this sort of thing, but adaptive syntax analysers needs to be able to cope with it — because people do, and thus so should they.

Comment: Get rid of your old grammar textbooks!

Answer (score 0):

At [English Forums: Adverbial Objectives?](https://www.englishforums.com/English/AdverbialObjectives/bvwmv/post.htm), there is an article listing quite a few **adverbial objectives** (nouns used as adverbs, or nouns used as if they were adverbs) by 'paco'. While I'd query the classification of some of his examples as adverbs / adverbial objectives, and the jury is out on whether the nouns have fully converted to adverbs, it's useful reading.