# Why does Polly want a cracker?

Tags: etymology, expressions

Where does the expression "Polly wants a cracker" come from? Why is the parrot named Polly, and why doesn't she want seeds?

Comment: "It's not enough to want a cracker. You have to earn it." H. Simpson

Answer (score 51, accepted):

While there are a number of sources that attribute the *origin* of this phrase to R.L. Stevenson's *[Treasure Island](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treasure_Island)* (pub. 1883), or alternatively, to the National Biscuit Company ([Nabisco](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabisco), c. [1876](http://www.ehow.com/about_5200517_history-saltine-crackers.html)) which used it as a popular slogan, neither of them *appears* to be the right one. As James McLeod has pointed out in another answer, "*Polly want a cracker*" can be verified to have been in use even before these dates.

The earliest entry in Google Books is from [*Bunkum Flag-Staf and Independent Echo*](http://books.google.com/books?id=2U4yAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22Polly%20want%20a%20cracker%22&pg=PA536#v=onepage&q=%22Polly%20want%20a%20cracker%22&f=false)", a satirical fake newspaper published in *The Knickerbocker* (or, New-York Monthly) magazine, Volume 34, in *1849*. The reference to Polly's crackers can be seen in the following excerpt:

[image: Bunkum Flag-Staf and Independent Echo, The Knickerbocker: Or, New-York Monthly Magazine, Volume 34, 1849]

A radio show named [*A Way with Words*](http://www.waywordradio.org/) has also attempted to [trace the roots](http://www.waywordradio.org/tweet-tweet-polly-wanna-cracker/) of this phrase. According to the host, the earliest reference he could find was the following cartoon from 1848 in another satirical magazine named *The John-Donkey*:
[image: Polly want a cracker?]

The use of *cracker* in the cartoon is a pun on the word for the biscuit as well as the fact that the boy is ready to *crack* the skull of the parrot open, presumably for annoying him (perhaps by asking him for a cracker?). The hosts of the show go on further to make a connection between the use of [crackers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cracker_%28food%29) on ships (as long-lasting food) and perhaps parrots being on board as well. At any rate, they conclude that even in 1848, parrots named Polly wanted crackers and that the phrase might have been commonly used.

Now, cracker biscuits were invented in 1801 (or perhaps earlier in 1792) which should date this phrase. Incidentally, the use of the name Polly for a parrot can [apparently be dated](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/8/messages/77.html) to at least [1606](http://arapaho.nsuok.edu/~mercer/3543/3543StudyGuide7.htm) to Ben Jonson's play, [Volpone](http://arapaho.nsuok.edu/~mercer/3543/3543StudyGuide7.htm). According to the source, the OED (somebody please clarify) expounds on this matter thusly:

> Polly is a diminutive of Poll "as a female name, and name for a parrot," and Poll, altered from Moll, familiar form of Mary, is the traditional name for any parrot. The earliest quotation the OED gives for Polly as a name or designation for a parrot is from Ben Jonson's "Epigrams," 1616.

In conclusion, there is no concrete proof of the exact origin of the phrase. However, my best guess is that crackers became the staple food/snack for pet parrots who ended up parroting their owners during feeding time - "Polly, want a cracker?". I believe that the phrase was popularised by Nabisco's slogan and has been in use ever since. In other words, this exercise was quite pointless; but, I wouldn't have it any other way :)

Comment: I asked my question because there were so many different explanations out there. Yours makes the most sense. Thank you!

Comment: @coleopterist: I've quoted some OED dates in my [answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/75618/9001).

Comment: This exercise is no more. It has ceased to be.

Comment: @BobRoberts, It is an EXercise.

Comment: " this exercise was quite pointless; but, I wouldn't have it any other way" - hahahaha spoken like a true etymologist.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not a parrot-fancier, but I suspect it may be easier to get a parrot to produce a recognisable rendition of the word "cracker" than "seed".

Parrots can be taught to say all sorts of things. I remember being in a dingily-lit country pub many years ago. Myself and my lady companion seemed to be the only customers, but every few minutes a voice coming from somewhere in the murk kept saying *"I've got my beady little **eye** on you!"*.

We were excruciatingly embarrassed for some time (we certainly stopped canoodling in the corner!). But then we heard ["Pieces of eight! Pieces of eight!"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22who%27s%20a%20pretty%20boy%20then%22%20parrot&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22Pieces%20of%20eight%22%20parrot&oq=%22Pieces%20of%20eight%22%20parrot&gs_l=serp.3...109165.110570.0.111553.2.2.0.0.0.0.74.119.2.2.0...0.0...1c.H5ryhZ5FYIE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=644001cab0275ea4&biw=1306&bih=862), and it finally dawned on us! Strangely, as I recall, it never said that other old standard for parrots - ["Who's a pretty boy, then?"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22who%27s%20a%20pretty%20boy%20then%22%20parrot&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

The [earliest reference](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Polly%20wants%20a%20cracker%22%20&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22Polly%20wants%20a%20cracker%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GHAMUIbQFqXK0QWgg72pCg&ved=0CCsQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1800,cd_max:31/12/1864&tbm=bks&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=644001cab0275ea4&biw=1306&bih=862) I can find is 1859, but I should think it was a fairly standard thing to teach parrots long before that. Bear in mind that usually (always?) the parrot has no concept of the *meaning* of whatever it says - after all, it *is* a bird-brain.

---

The owner of that bar obviously thought it would be fun to have his parrot say something that might sometimes seem "context-relevant". Sailors would perforce eat "crackers" (dry hard biscuits, suitable for long sea-voyages). Our archetypal parrot-owning sailor would thus have them on hand to offer as a reward when training the parrot; naturally he'd start by teaching it to ask for them. Besides – poor fare though it might be – he'd only have a limited ration of crackers (as with his [rum ration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rum_ration)). He'd want to get his parrot up to speed with *"Polly wants a cracker"*, if only so his ship-mates would say...

> *"Ah! Isn't he cute! He wants a bite of our hard tack, too!"*

...and offer the parrot bits of *their* ration.

Okay - I know *archetypal* sailors would say *"Arrggghhhh!"*, but the point is they probably wouldn't have *seed* on board, so the "anthropomorphism" wouldn't work with that version. And the parrot often wouldn't be saying *either* version because he actually wanted anything to eat at all, let alone a specific food (he just likes attention). So from his point of view it's irrelevant what word he says.

---

As regards why *"Polly"* is a traditional name for a tame parrot, OED has this to say...

> **Poll** [An alteration of Moll, a familiar equivalent of Mary: cf. Peg = Meg, Margaret.]
>
> A familiar equivalent of the name Mary (see also Polly1), used as the conventional proper name of any parrot; hence, = parrot. So Poll-ˈparrot, also used fig., and attrib., with reference to the parrot's unintelligent repetition of words.

Comment: Some parrots know whereof they speak. Most don’t.

Comment: @tchrist: Clearly the vast majority don't - hence the verb [to parrot](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/parrot)

Comment: I'd give you an additional +1 for the story if I could.

Comment: @Noah: *My* answer (which obviously isn't the longest here) goes into one of the significant reasons for teaching a parrot to say anything at all. My "digression" into the pub-parrot was relevant to that, **and** took up less "column-inches" than a Victorian cartoon that simply raises an irrelevant alternative meaning of the word "cracker".

Answer (score 8):

**Why is the parrot named Polly?**

The OED's earliest quote for *Polly* (a parrot) is from 1826, but in the etymology section says Ben Jonson used it in his 1616 *Epigrams* referring to two people, a Robert Pooley and a Parrot, and that there may be a pun:

> And we will haue no Pooly' or Parrot by.

Further, it notes Johnson's use of *Poll* (a name for a parrot) *Every Man Out of His Humor* from 1600:

> *Fast.* Would you speake to mee Sir?
>   *Carl.* I, when he has recouered himselfe: poore Poll.

So the female forename Polly comes from the female forename Poll (also Pall), and was originally a rhyming variant of Moll, which is a diminutive of Mary.

Daniel Defoe's *Robinson Crusoe* ([1719](http://www.pierre-marteau.com/editions/1719-robinson-crusoe.html)) named his parrot Poll and taught him to speak, and in a much later [1894](http://books.google.fi/books?id=amwAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=%22polly%20wants%22%20OR%20%22poll%20wants%22%20OR%20%22polly%20want%22%20OR%20%22poll%20want%22&source=bl&ots=wcHimL7-oX&sig=cEPffnGSQNy090-lWFnk_MyP8Z8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=diQNUI-CCcSB4gTaq6jMCg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22polly%20wants%22%20OR%20%22poll%20wants%22%20OR%20%22polly%20want%22%20OR%20%22poll%20want%22&f=false) children's version the parrot said "Polly wants a cracker, cracker."

(The OED's earliest quote for *cracker* (thin hard biscuit) is from 1739.)

---

**Why doesn't she want seeds?**

Polly didn't demand a cracker. In 1831 she wanted breakfast and tea, according to the [*The London Literary Gazette*](http://books.google.fi/books?id=TyMAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA647&lpg=PA647&dq=%22polly%20wants%22%20OR%20%22poll%20wants%22%20OR%20%22polly%20want%22%20OR%20%22poll%20want%22&source=bl&ots=btpY9xWgYv&sig=7okNdQtGR54T2Mb2ygVdhytCE04&hl=en&sa=X&ei=diQNUI-CCcSB4gTaq6jMCg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=true):

[image: A friend of mine knew one that had been taught many sentences ; thus - ' Sally, Poll wants her breakfast !' ' Sally, Poll wants her tea !' but she never mistook the one for the other ; breakfast was invariably demanded in the morning, and tea in ...]

> A friend of mine knew one that had been taught many sentences ; thus - **' Sally, Poll wants her breakfast !' ' Sally, Poll wants her tea !'** but she never mistook the one for the other ; breakfast was invariably demanded in the morning, and tea in the afternoon.

Comment: Polly became cheap over the years, I guess. +1!

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it is possible to answer this question. "Polly" is a traditional name for a parrot, dating back an awfully long time (as is the expression, as shown by this [Google NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Polly+wants+a+cracker%2CPolly+want+a+cracker&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Perhaps a cracker is a special treat to be offered as a change from seed?

Comment: Because there were no seeds aboard the pirate ship, only biccies.

Comment: @tchrist: Arrggghhh! It took me ages to write my answer, effectively saying exactly that! Which I wouldn't have bothered with if I'd waited one minute longer and seen your comment first.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Wit’s soul wins. :)

Comment: @tchrist: Ah, but in this specific context, *"Arrggghhhh"* is scissors, and *"Ah!"* is mere paper. :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think you ducked Polonius’s advice. But I parroted it.

Comment: @tchrist: Polonius Bolonyus! I just accepted your [astonishingly long answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/what-exactly-is-an-adverb)!

Comment: @FumbleFingers My point was that sometimes brevity (=Polonius’s soul of wit, =wit’s soul) beats out typing.

Comment: @tchrist: I can see that a goodly portion of your answer was indeed "parroted" (by cut & paste), but there was a lot that you must have typed. I'm pretty fast for a two-fingered typist, but still hopelessly slow compared to you guys who use all fingers on both hands. That's one of the reasons I don't go on chat much here - I just can't keep up!

Answer (score 1):

The Parrot is called Pol, i.e. Polly, already in John Skelton's Speke, Parrot (1521), where it wants an almond, crackers not having been invented yet.

Answer (score -1):

Wow, is this a Nirvana reference? Polly is a parakeet also used in this way. It's a derogatory way of saying, I'll give you a minor reward for doing what I tell you to do... and it has been conditioned to comply.