# Why is "thought" (verb III) a noun in "Nice thought"?

Tags: verbs, gerunds, noun-phrases

I often hear someone says, "Wow, that's such a nice thought!"

Movies and books often have that kind of dialogue as well.

As I figure it out, "a nice thought" is a noun phrase. Which means "nice" is a complementary for "thought", and "thought" is literally a *noun*.

I'm also aware that *thought* is a third form (or second) of *think*, and dictionaries say that *thought* is a noun, too.

But why not use *thinking* (gerund) instead of *thought*? As I understand it, gerund has a function to make a verb-ing function as a noun.

Are there other third-form verbs that also function as nouns? Or is it just *thought*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Past participle used as a noun?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77587/past-participle-used-as-a-noun)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't know this is a participle case, so I failed to foresee this is a possible duplicate.

Comment: @Safira: Don't apologize. The best one can say about finding answers here is _belum jadi_.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Wow. You speak Indonesian. Yea, thank you. Still new here :)

Comment: Actually, I learned it in Malaysia, not Indonesia. But it's Bahasa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Thought* is the *past participle* of *think* (I guess that is what you mean by the "third form", though I've never heard that phrase: is it used in teaching EFL?)

Participles combine some of the functions of adjectives with some of the functions of verbs. Some can be used as regular adjectives (eg *baked* in *baked goods*).

Others have more limited distribution, so you wouldn't normally say **a thought idea*; but you can say *an idea thought but not spoken*, where *thought* (and *spoken*) have adjectival force.

Many adjectives can be used as nouns, eg *the poor*; this is less common in Modern English than in earlier forms of the language. Many nouns were originally adjectives used in this way, eg *centenary* (and *centennial*).

*Thought* as a noun is one of these: originally it was a participle, functioning as an adjective, and came to be used as a noun meaning *thing thought*.

Comment: Very nice answer, thanks. The "third form" I mean is the one on these: *see, saw, **seen***, *make, made, **made***, *think, thought, **thought***. What do native speakers call these forms of verbs? And yea, it is used in teaching EFL (in my country).

Comment: The form **think** is also used as a noun, but only in the phrase "If you think that, you've got another think coming".

Answer (score 1):

"Thought" is, as you said, literally [a noun](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thought):

> an idea, plan, opinion, picture, etc., that is formed in your mind : something that you think of.

The key there is that it's **a** thought - generally a singular idea.  This fits with the idiom "a nice thought" because you're talking about the idea they had.

Thinking can also be used as a noun in gerund form, but here you're talking more about the **act** of thinking:

> "Wow, that's some sharp thinking."

I can't think of an exhaustive list of verbs that fit this pattern, but two that come immediately to mind are "walk" and "drive".

> We went for a nice walk.  He took a long drive.  <-- meaning a singular trip.
>
> He did some fancy driving.  That's some fast walking.  <-- the act of driving/walking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Actually, what bothers me is that why is it the third form of "think" that functions as a noun (Verb 3)? While for the other verbs, like "walk" or "drive" you said, the ones that functions as nouns are the first forms of the verbs (Verb 1).

Comment: Because _think_ is transitive. A _thought_ is a thing which has been thought by somebody. _Walk_ is intransitive (doesn't take an object), and while _drive_ can be transitive, the object is the vehicle, not the drive, so a _drive_ is not something which is _driven_. However, this is not the whole of the answer, because a _feeling_ (not "a felt", which doesn't exist in this sense) is what is _felt_. The rest of the answer is "because that is how it is": there aren't always explanations.