# What is the word for a past-tense verb used like a gerund?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, gerunds, gerund-phrases

In a comment on [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/133764/51896) to a similar question, the user [Kris](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/14666/kris) identifies the concept of "a member of a class to which gerunds belong but itself [is] not a gerund." Is there a word for such a thing? For example, the inverse of "the *taunting* boy" is "the *taunted girl*". I believe the first phrase is a gerund. What kind of thing is the second phrase?

Comment: It's a participle.

Comment: A past participial adjective. I wouldn't call the present participial adjective (the taunting boy) a gerund, either.

Comment: The title of the linked question is *past participle used as a noun* the OP which contains Kris's comment talks about *past participle*, the higher rated answers talk about the past participle [*. . . damned, beloved and all the others are adjectives which derive from verbs, hence the -ed suffix, characteristic of the past participle.*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/77593/44619)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try to construct a past tense verb used as a gerund.  A gerund is a verb in nominal position, and it cannot be tensed (i.e., it must be non-finite).  A past tense verb which is made non-finite comes to be perfect, as for instance when we convert "It seems that he ate fish last night" into infinitive form: "He seems to have eaten fish last night".  So, for our construction, we can expect to have a perfect aspect form.

A nominal position is one that requires a noun phrase, which is a phrase type which can occur as subject, object, and elsewhere, so let's try to put a clause with a past verb into subject position.  Starting with a *that*-clause construction, "That he ate fish surprises us" and converting to a non-finite gerund construction, we get "His having eaten fish surprises us", which is perfectly grammatical.

So, it is possible to have a past tense verb used as a gerund, provided you allow for the conversion of past tense to perfect aspect, which is found elsewhere when a past tense is put into a grammatical construction that does not allow a tensed verb.

Your examples have verbs in adjectival positions, modifying nouns, but for a gerund, you want to find a verb in nominal position.  A verb in adjectival position is a participle, not a gerund.