# What part of speech would these words be considered as?

Tags: parts-of-speech

I am trying to figure out what part of speech the bolded words are:

> Spanish is **spoken** in parts of South America

and,

> Football is **played** in America.

Answer (score 2):

The form you pointed out in your question is called a past participle (of a verb). Together with the verb "to be", it forms the passive voice (*Spanish is spoken...*)

Past participles can function as different types of speech in the English language and it all boils down to how you define a particular type of speech. There's a great explanation of it on an older thread in this Stack Exchange: [Past participle used as a noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/77592/169916)

There is also another thread that doesn't talk about participles but explains the viewpoints behind different types of speech which may be useful to you: [What exactly is an "adverb"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/what-exactly-is-an-adverb/75510#75510)