# Is "messaging" a noun, a verb, or an adjective?

Tags: verbs, parts-of-speech

In the cruel jargon of software, it is common to see the phrase "[messaging system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_messaging_system)", as if "messaging" were an adjective. Yet if I am "brushing" my teeth, it's a verb. There is an act of "brushing", and I suppose I could invent a "brushing device".

Is the answer that it is all three parts of speech? If so, what is the name for this kind of word, formed from a verb and made so awkwardly useful?

Comment: In answer to your question: yes. see [gerund](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gerund?q=gerund) and [participle](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/participle?q=participle).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly is an "adverb"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/what-exactly-is-an-adverb)

Comment: ... I know that's talking about a different "part of speech", but the same answer applies. In this case, ***messaging** software* is an adjective, *"I've been **messaging** him all day"* is a verb, and for me at least, *"I use my iPod for everyday tasks such as **messaging**"* is effectively a "noun" usage. Most English words can be used in several different ways, which means they fill different "parts of speech".

Comment: The 'messaging' in messaging software isn't really an adjective. There is a single intellectual concept of "messaging software" so it's better understood as a compound noun.

Comment: If *messaging* were a *participle*, which is what we call an *-ing* form employed as an adjective, *messaging software* would be *software which messages*.  *Messaging* here is a *gerund*, which is what we call an *-ing* form employed as a noun; but it's a gerund employed attributively (which may be called *adjectivally*), as any noun may be used, equivalent to *software **for** messaging*. Compare *running man* (participle) and *running shoes* (attributive gerund).

Comment: @MattЭллен, you should make your answer and actual answer, not a comment! I'd like to accept it.

Comment: There is not a noun which cannot be verbed.
SCNR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. *Messaging* fits in the three parts of speech listed.

Firstly there is the verb [*to message*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/message?q=message#message__15) which is transitive and can be used in all the usual ways, e.g.:

> I message people all the time.
>
> Yes, Tony! I'm **messaging** them now!
>
> I've messaged them, OK? Get off my back. Gah!

So you can see *messaging* being used in the present continuous sense.

Then there is the use of the present continuous sense as a noun, often referred to as the [gerund](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gerund?q=gerund).

> The **messaging** will take place at 3pm today.

And thirdly there is the use of the present continuous where an adjective would go, which is often referred to as the [participle](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/participle?q=participle). The example in the question of *messaging system* is a good example of that. You can see that *messaging* is modifying *system* much like *red* or *unlucky* would.

As far as I know, all transitive verbs work like this.

Comment: I’m not so sure of that. I think in *messaging system*, that the word is a gerund and thus a noun. Think of one’s *messaging style*: that is certainly being a noun there. Sometimes it’s hard to tell; with *running shoes*, you have *running* as a noun, but with *running water*, it is an adjective. One test is to try to use the word predicatively: *“Is the water running?”* Yes, so it is an adjective, but *“Are the shoes running?”* No: they are shoes ***for*** running, so it is a noun. With *messaging system*, it seems to fail to predicate test, at least for me.

Comment: Depends on how you look at it. It's either a system for messaging or a system that is messaging.

Comment: @tchrist In _messaging system_ are you talking about the _messaging_ or the _system_? _system_ is the noun, so _messaging_ is being used as an adjective as it's describing a type of system. The same applies to your other examples. It's like _water bowl_. _water_ is a noun that is being used as an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

It can be all three!

> Messaging is fun!

noun

> I'm messaging my great-uncle Jehoshaphat.

verb

> Have you downloaded the new messaging app?

adjective

These are [polysemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy) of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson.  Your #2 use of "messaging" is the present participle used as part of a verb phrase.  The present participle used alone is either a type of noun (a gerund) or an adjective. When used in combination with another active verb (in this case - am) it is a verb phrase. Some call this construction the Progressive; others call it the Continuous. In this case, with a present indicative form of "am" I think it is the Present Progessive.

Answer (score -1):

An adjective tells you more about a noun. So in the case of "Messaging System", the "Messaging" tells you more about the System, making it an adjective.