# When is "here" an adverb or a noun?

Tags: nouns, adverbs, syntactic-analysis, parts-of-speech

In the sentence "I hope you are all paying attention, here is a sentence I made earlier", is *here* an adverb or a noun? I think it is a noun, but if I substitute a noun or a pronoun for *here*, the sentence loses its intended meaning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What part of speech does “here” have in “I am here”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111058/what-part-of-speech-does-here-have-in-i-am-here)

Comment: Or possibly [What exactly is an adverb?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/what-exactly-is-an-adverb)

Comment: I have to say this is a very strange question, because unlike other people wondering about such things you're actually aware of the easy test, *and* have already performed it, *and* concluded that it can't be a noun... and now are still thinking it could be one. I have to ask: why? And what, then, was the purpose of the test in the first place if you won't accept the results you get?

Comment: Neither of these previous answers deal with the change of meaning when "here" is substituted by a noun. In the sentence "I am here," "here" can be substituted with "in the wardrobe," which could be regarded as an indirect object or a prepositional clause (I am not clear as to which it is). When "here" is acting as the subject of a sentence, e.g., in the wardrobe is a sentence I made earlier, can it still be regarded as a noun? (Maybe,

Comment: I seem to have divided opinion with this question, but thanks RegDwight for confirming my opinion, but I'll be only too glad to hear other opinions.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: I'm assuming this is a case where you apply the test you know but don't find the answer satisfying so you doubt your approach, doubt the test, doubt if the test was applicable, doubt if you tested properly, and then go ask the experts at English Language & Usage. Wherever the mistake was we should be able to help. Function words and adverbs can be tricky when shoehorned into the part-of-speech system.

Comment: I don't know how much use *substitution* is in this context. *Here is a sentence I wrote just now ... Here is a man I met just now ... **John** is a man I met just now*. By that logic, obviously we can substitute a noun for *here*. I'd say it's because *here = **[this]** here*. I have no problem accepting ***this*** as a pronoun generally meaning *this thing **here***.

Comment: I think this is a great question! :) -- This brings up the difference between function and category. Some more examples which might be somewhat similar to the OP's example: *"Here is where the accident occurred."* (*"Is here where the accident occurred?"*), *"Under the table is a good place to hide"* (*"Is under the table a good place to hide?"*), *"Here is where we should put it."* (*"Is here where we should put it?"*). -- Perhaps also consider the possibility of "here" as being an intransitive preposition. . . .

Comment: *Here* is not an adverb or a noun It is a preposition.

Comment: @Araucaria why don't you answer this question? And explain why "here" is not an adverb.

Comment: It's a comma splice.

Answer (score 2):

[John Lawler notes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112556/when-is-here-an-adverb-or-a-noun#comment228720_112558) in a comment on a different answer here:

> Alas, no. It's still an adverb. The construction *Here/There is/are `Noun Phrase`* allows the adverb to be fronted, with the subject `Noun Phrase` moved to the end, as the new information. It's said either referring to a physical place (pointing is appropriate), or metaphorically to refer to things that are being said in the conversation. *Here is `X`* generally means 'The next thing I say is `X`'.

Comment: If "here" is used as location, as in "I am still here", then I do not understand by what reason it is not considered a noun. Furthermore, I do not understand what it modifies in the example above. Perhaps this is one of those weird situations in the English language where we have a made up rule that became a tradition.

Comment: If you consider it a noun, it has to be a predicate noun following auxiliary _be_. And the predicate is a locative, which can take many forms, for which _here_ and _there_ are pro-forms. If you want to call the pro-forms prepositions, why not? It doesn't matter how one labels intermediate nodes, after all.

Answer (score 0):

according to dictionary.com, the word 'here' can be a noun as in this example "It's only a short distance from here."

Answer (score 0):

the sentence, "I hope you are all paying attention, here is a sentence I made earlier" is a type of run-on sentence known as a comma splice. correctly written it should read. "I hope you are all paying attention. Here is a sentence I made earlier." Rewritten correctly, "Here" becomes the subject of the second sentence and thus, a noun

looking at it a different way, an adverb is a word that modifies a verb. In either the original sentences or my rewritten version "Here" is not modifying a verb or anything else for that matter and thus is not an adverb.

Answer (score -2):

You're correct, "here" is a noun.

Comment: Alas, no. It's still an adverb. The construction _Here/There is/are `Noun Phrase`_ allows the adverb to be fronted, with the subject `Noun Phrase` moved to the end, as the new information. It's said either referring to a physical place (pointing is appropriate), or metaphorically to refer to things that are being said in the conversation. _Here is `X`_ generally means 'The next thing I say is `X`'.

Comment: Thanks, John Lawler, but your answer is a little confusing for me.

Comment: Jonn Lawler is saying that _Here is my car_ has exactly the same components as _My car is here_. And he debunks both the noun and adverb theories for _here_ in either permutation in tchrist's link above. And he would probably not agree with my labelling _here_'s word class in this usage as _locative particle_, as he  concentrates on constructions.

Comment: Thanks, Edwin, but I really didn't get it as I don't know what a locative partiple is, but I'm on to it right now and hope to be familiar with the term very shortly.

Comment: You probably won't find the term - the argument still rages. Most people interested in this field try to use a word-class structure to help with the analysis of English, but most don't agree on which one to use. Many would admit that classifying this usage of _here_ as either noun or adverb is counter-intuitive and counter-productive; if anything, _John is here_ models on _John is cold_, where the extra information is about John rather than the 'being' (ie existing) - and so adjectival. But moving to _John came here_; _John is home (now)_, we see that the label 'adjective' is also wrong.

Comment: Well, in my previous question that I made earlier "Hello, Denver, Charlotte calling, here are the results of the test." (closed by english.stackexchange for not being a permissable question): Wot you think?

Comment: Read before posting to see whether it's fair to expect others to understand exactly what you're asking. The analyses of your examples look very similar, if that's what you're after (or even if it's not).

Comment: The only case where I can think of that "here" is a noun is in the set phrase "the here and now," and that's a different case from the question.

Comment: @gmcgath: _They left here yesterday_ arguably uses 'here' as a noun.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well, if *here* is **not** a noun in your example, then *school* is not a noun in *I left school at 16*   or *work* in *I left work at 3 o’oclock.*