# 'there' adverb,pronoun or preposition?

Tags: adverbs

He was there.

In this sentence is ' there ' an adverb?

I get very confused when I have to identify parts of speech.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of '[What part of speech does “here” have in “I am here”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111058/what-part-of-speech-does-here-have-in-i-am-here)' See J Lawler's answer.  But 'there' in 'He was there' is a _distal_ locative (some would add 'intransitive preposition'). But many people still consider it in the 'adverb' class.

Comment: @tchrist Hmm. *Here* is proximal, *there* is distal. In any case ljawler's answer in the linked-to page only gives its syntactic function (predicate), not its PoS. On the other hand [here is a page which actually deals with *there*, not *here* and does, in fact address the question of PoS!](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182975/is-there-an-adverb-or-a-preposition-or-something-else-entirely) Could we change the dupe it's linked to, by any chance, please?

Comment: That's a very interesting tack that CGEL takes, defining _here_ and _there_ as mostly intransitive prepositions. It sort of works. But it really just points to the irrelevance of wanting a POS label for every possible word. POS are useful only for substantive words, and not even always even then. Anything that can get caught in the machinery just needs a part number, not a designation.