# 'These here' phrases - why here?

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning

#### What is the etymology of the '*here*' in the expression '**these here**'?

I am unable to find a dictionary definition, although I believe the expression could also be simply *these*, or even *those*.  So why did the '*these here*' construct come about? It sounds like dialect, which isn't always explainable, but I'd appreciate any actual references to why and where it came about.
An example is:

> Probably she was one of **these here** New Women. (The Wheels of Chance, H.G. Wells)

---

It also can be formed with other demonstrative determiners, while using either adverb 'here' or 'there', for example:

> - This here
> - Those here
> - That there

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221521/a-question-about-this-here-adjective

Comment: @Davo - oops, didn't see that.. thanks!

Comment: "This here" and its cousins are generally regarded as "illiterate" speech.

Comment: @HotLicks what do you mean by 'illiterate speech'?

Comment: @marcellothearcane - Speech by people who have not had a significant amount of formal education in English, and who were not raised in homes where the speech was reasonably formal.  Eg, *The Beverly Hillbillies*.

Comment: @HotLicks The book I'm reading is BrE, with the person saying it being an outfitter's clerk, who seems to be in a formal environment.  Also, a Butler says it in [Wodehouse](http://www.online-literature.com/pg-wodehouse/something-new/5/) - I know they're only books, but there's generally a certain amount of realisticness.

Comment: Look at the context -- "these here New Women".  The guy is speaking sarcastically, and using an "illiterate" idiom emphasizes that.  As to Wodehouse, he wrote most of his stuff while residing in the US, and was intentionally creating a caricature of British "upper crust" society.

Comment: Note that Beach's diction, although pompous, is not altogether correct: in the same speech you find "it don't seem hardly necessary" and "I had to speak severe".

Comment: @StoneyB what does this entail? A layman buttling? or a fad of the day?

Comment: Beach, although he has acquired a "dignified inertia" and "distilled speech" suitable to his exalted position at Blandings, is not highly educated: he doubtless started as an ordinary footman and rose from the ranks. And his taste for sensational journalism suggests little acquaintance with such Higher Literature as might have remedied his educational deficiencies.

Comment: @StoneyB good points, thanks - I suppose the comedic effect of a 'snooty' butler using 'wrong' English could have been a motive too...