# On the part of speech of "now"

Tags: nouns, adverbs, time, syntactic-analysis, deixis

I recently had a conversation about the Spanish word "ahora", in which my conversant claimed that "ahora" is *always* an adverb, and never a noun.

This lead me to investigate the part of speech of similar words, both in Spanish and English (my native language).  According to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/now), "now" *can* be a noun, as in:

> ### noun
>
> 10.
>   the present time or moment:
>   *"Up to now no one has volunteered."*

What makes "now" a noun in this context?  In the Spanish equivalent of the example ("Hasta ahora..."), "ahora" is considered an adverb by the dictionaries I checked with.

The gist of the question: How can I know when *now* (or any word, for that matter--especially one which is commonly an adverb) is a noun? What test can be applied?

In the example quoted above ("Up to now...") it is not at all obvious to me why 'now' should be a noun while with, say "Until tomorrow", 'tomorrow' is an adverb. They seem like the same grammatical construct to me, so I would (apparently quite naively) expect the same part of speech to follow "Up to" or "Until."

Comment: Well, one context where you can easily recognise that ***now*** is functioning as a noun is when it's the grammatical *subject* in a sentence. For example, [*Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the party*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22now+is+the+time+for+all%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). But why pick on that word in particular? You might as well ask *"How can I establish whether **any** given word is being used as a noun in any given sentence?"*

Comment: How would you express the concept of "The *Eternal Now*" in Spanish? What would "The *Long Now* Foundation" be named, instead? How would you say "I'm trying to live *in the now*" or "*the here and now*"? Are these really all adverbial phrases in Spanish?

Comment: Related: [*What exactly is an “adverb”?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/what-exactly-is-an-adverb). Perhaps we should change the title of this question to *What exactly is a “noun”?*, and locate & retitle (or create) similar questions for *verb, adjective,*, etc.

Comment: @DanBron: "the here and now" is an idomatic phrase which in Spanish is more commonly stated, I think, as "el día de hoy" (literally "the day of today" but more in line with "these days" or "today" (in the 'here and now' sense)).

Comment: In *until tomorrow*, the word *tomorrow* is also a noun. Why do you think it's an adverb?

Comment: @PeterShor: [I thought so, too](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17221622#17221622), but [others disagree](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17221638#17221638).

Comment: @PeterShor: He is disagreeing. He was responding directly to my statement that tomorrow is a noun in "Until tomorrow." If you read the rest of the conversation it may be more apparent to you that he was indeed disagreeing :)

Comment: Both *tomorrow* and *yesterday* can be nouns. Consider Shakespeare *"And all our yesterdays have lighted fools
The way to dusty death."* And consider *tomorrow's weather*; if something can take a possessive, it has to be a noun. I don't see why they shouldn't be ones in *since yesterday* and *until tomorrow*.

Comment: @PeterShor: Can be, yes. But are they in this case? That's the question. And why or why not?

Comment: Flimzy I've added the appropriate definition in my answer that explains why or why not.

Comment: @PeterShor I was getting there, Peter, I was getting there. :) These tomes are not written in a trice.

Comment: Of course, people do say [*until soon*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=until+soon%2Cuntil+next+week&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuntil%20soon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuntil%20next%20week%3B%2Cc0), and *"soon"* is clearly an adverb. So there is some justification for saying *tomorrow* and *now* are adverbs in *until tomorrow* and *until now*.

Comment: @PeterShor Disagree. A prepositional phrase = PREPOSITION + NOUN_PHRASE. You can place whatever constituent you like there for NOUN_PHRASE.  This is true in all circumstances.  It does not mean that the thingy dangling at the tail is no longer an NP even if it started out live as an adverb.  It *has* to be an NP.

Comment: PeterShor and tchrist per the dictionary.reference.com definition I referenced in my answer, if "until" is followed by something that generally means a pre-definable time (6pm, night, or tomorrow) then "until" is a preposition and if only a single word follows that word is necessarily a noun.  If "until" is followed by something non-time-specific (such as when guests happen to arrive or in this case "soon") then "until" is a conjunction and if a single word follows that word is an adverb.  See my answer for more clarification.

Comment: @PeterShor Even more plainly, people say "until recently".

Comment: @JoeZ, Peter: I think you’re making the wrong inference. It is not that because people say *until recently* or *until soon* that makes *until now* and *until tomorrow* have adverbs as objects of that preposition, but rather it is the preposition that makes all four of *recently*, *soon*, *now*, and *tomorrow* into something more substantive than ever they could be when modifying verbs. It doesn’t matter what you call it: it is functioning as an NP. Since there is only one word after the preposition, and we know that that word must be an NP, it necessarily follows that it is acting like a noun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### tl;dr:

Certain kinds of words and phrases can in English function equally well as nouns as they can adverbs.  Whether you prefer to call them nouns acting like adverbs or adverbs acting like nouns is a matter of religion only, since they are still doing the same job no matter what you call them.

The job they are doing is a ***deictic*** one, described at the end of this post.

---

## *“Now, now!”*

Please do not be surprised  that “dictionary.com” — or any other dictionary, for that matter — should have gotten this wrong.  Grammar is not a dictionary’s strong point to begin with; it is a lexicon, not a grammar.  But many dictionaries are still trapped in the fourth century when it comes to parts of speech, and modern syntactic analysis is not.

I would take especial care in crowd-sourced or unattributed “dictionaries”.  This includes things like Wikipedia and Wiktionary, and it especially includes any reference as hip and now as Urban Dictionary.

Both nouns and adverbs can be drafted into doing the other one’s normal job.    For example, when you say you did something last week, you are using the noun phrase *last week* adverbially. That doesn’t make *week* an adverb, though.  Furthermore, this is as true in Spanish as it is in English: *Lo hice la semana pasada* does the very same thing. In both languages, it’s a simple adverbial phrase that happens to be noun phrase as well.

For your purposes, you want to see whether the noun–adverb swap can work the other way, too, particularly for the word *now*.  And the answer is that it can.

To prove that *now* can act as a noun in English is most easily accomplished by showing it inflected into the plural or by using it as the subject of a verb, preferably as the head noun of a longer noun phrase with traditional prenominal adornments like determiners and adjectives prefacing it.

All these things are easily done.

Furthermore, to show that this is an age-old practice in English and not some flash-in-the-pan phenom pulled out of the Urban Dictionary’s backside, I shall begin in literature of the now-distant past.

In act 2 scene 2 of *Timon of Athens*, probably written around 1605, Shakespeare wrote:

> O my good lord,
>   At many times I brought in my accounts,
>   Laid them before you; you would throw them off,
>   And say, you found them in mine honesty.
>   When, for some trifling present, you have bid me
>   Return so much, I have shook my head and wept;
>   Yea, ’gainst the authority of manners, pray’d you
>   To hold your hand more close: I did endure
>   Not seldom, nor no slight cheques, when I have
>   Prompted you in the ebb of your estate
>   And your great flow of debts. My loved lord,
>   Though you hear now, too late—**yet now’s a time**—
>   The greatest of your having lacks a half
>   To pay your present debts.

That has *now* serving as the subject of *be*, or so it appears.  Some might try to argue that use in a copula may not be good enough evidence, and for those, not even this more famous citation from the start of *Richard III* (probably written around 1592) suffices:

> **Now** is the winter of our discontent
>   Made glorious summer by this sun of York;
>   And all the clouds that lour’d upon our house
>   In the deep bosom of the ocean buried.

I think those are enough, but some disagree, claiming that it is fine to have adverbs to either side of a copula:

- Soon is immediately.
- Often is always.
- Quickly is carefully.

I disagree.  After all, *winter* is obviously no adverb in *Now is the winter*, and neither is *now*.  But I do not wish to argue this with them, having yet stronger evidence to present.

Skipping forward a century, in 1711’s *The Works of the Right Reverend, Learned and Pious, Thomas Ken: Preparatives for Death* we find these half-dozen examples:

> On **the short Nows** God sends,
>   My everlasting state depends;
>   And should I but **this Now**
>   To cultivate my soul allow,
>   Short as it is, ’twould me prepare
>   To be of bliss eternal heir.
>
> I oft made solemn vows
>   To consecrate to God **my Nows**;
>   **This Now**, I would begin,
>   But worldly thoughts keep rushing in;
>   Then I the next, and next designed,
>   When the next came, I change my mine.
>
> I by experience found
>   The more I to the world gave ground,
>   The less my soul would heed
>   **The Nows** God for my good decreed;
>   When sin was up to habit wrought,
>   **Of Now** I seldom had a thought.

All but the sixth are clearly nouns: they have determiners in front of them like *this*, *the*, and *my*; and they are thrice inflected into the plural *nows*.  Only nouns can do those things, and so that these must here be nouns no question can remain.

Jumping ahead one more century to 1820, Sir Walter Scott wrote in *The Monastery*:

> “There are actions, father,” returned Edward, “which brook no delay, and this is one. It must be done **this very now**; or it may never be done.”

The OED considers that a substantive (that is, noun) use of *now*.

As a constituent, *this very now* is clearly acting adverbially to describe when something must be done.  But when you look inside that constituent, you clearly find a noun phrase.  We do not use *this* on anything but a noun, and *very* is there an adjective, not an adverb.  We do not apply adjectives to adverbs, but to substantives. Therefore this *now* can be nothing other than a noun.

If you removed the two front words from the adverbial noun phrase *this very now* in the Scott citation and produced therefore this compressed version:

> “There are actions, father,” returned Edward, “which brook no delay, and this is one. It must be done **<s>this very</s> now**; or it may never be done.”

If *now* must be a noun in *this very now*, even when used adverbially, mustn’t *now* also be noun when stripped of the pieces we used to prove it a noun, the *this* and the *very*?

### The sticky bit

We now come to the primary sticking point for most people: they don’t think that when *now* is used as a prepositional complement it has to be an noun. They think it might still be an adverb. Returning to the Ken citation given above, the final example is one of those places where some will argue that *now* has to be an adverb.

That sixth example is *Of Now I seldom had a thought*, or in more conventional ordering, *I seldom had a thought of Now*.  I maintain that this must also be a noun, even if for no other reason that the previous five examples given immediately before it are so clearly nouns, that then so too must it also be a noun.

Those who dispute this position believe that that a prepositional phrase need not inevitably supply a nominal complement to the preposition.

- until now
- until today
- until yesterday
- until midsummer eve
- until I’m good and ready
- until the cows come home
- until finished

I am discontent with calling any of those complements “adverbs”.  The clause examples are larger constituents, but do please that the last example of *finished* does not actually have a past participle serving as the prepositional complement. This is actually a reduced clause for something like *until it is finished* or *until you are finished*, with the obvious elision of something that in any larger context would be so obvious as to allow for its omission.

I really believe that all those prepositional objects are acting as nouns, one way or the other.  I do not believe we can just stick any old adverb in there and have things work.  These are all ungrammatical:

- until besides
- until instantly
- until soonest
- until out in back

Nonetheless, some adverbs clearly do work fine there:

- until recently
- until lately

At which point one might reasonably ask how there can be any difference between *until now* and *until recently*.

The answer, I believe, is that there is not one.  But that does not mean those are adverbs there.  I think it is better to analyse those not as adverbs but as [adverbs acting as nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/75510).

I’m afraid that the eight sacred parts of speech enumerated by Donatius back in the fourth century are not sufficient for modern syntactic analysis.  However, many dictionaries refuse to step away from them, and that is why you find such things in them.  They do not admit the notion that what is sometimes an adverb may at other times be a noun.

### Thus spake Oxford

The OED, however, is not one of those.  It points out many places that *now* can be a noun (or a substantive — *un sustantivo, como quieras*). My citations given above were all originally from the OED’s noun examples, although I gave them a fuller treatment than it did.

The OED attests *now* used as an adverb, as a conjunction, as a noun, and as an adjective.<sup>1</sup>  The adverbial and conjunctive uses are in sections I an II of that entry, the substantive uses in section III, and the attributive and adjectival uses are in section IV.

<sub>1. All four of which have I used at least once is this posting. :)</sub>

Interestingly, the uses with a preposition are not in section I; they are in section III with the other noun uses.  I therefore present section III for your contemplation:

> **III.** **13.** **a.** With preps., as ***by***, ***ere***, ***for***, ***or***, ***till***, ***unto***, ***now***.
>
> - **C. 825** *Vesp. Psalter* lxx. 17 ― Oð nu ic forðsecʒu wundur ðin.
>
>   **C. 1200** Ormin 14066 ― And tu þe gode win till nu Aȝȝ hafesst hidd and haldenn.
>
>   **A. 1300** *Cursor M.* 12800 ― Es þou helias halden til nu, Crist or prophet, quam to bu?
>
>   **C. 1450** *Cursor M.* 17785 (Laud), ― Ye wold nevir yt leve or now.
>
>   **C. 1450** tr. *De Imitatione* i. xxiv. 35 ― If þou haddist lyued unto now in worshipes & lustes of þe worlde.
>
>   **C. 1500** *Melusine* 121 ― But as for now I shall reste of hym and I shal retourne there.
>
>   **1592** Shaks. *Ven. & Ad.* 1062 ― Her eyes are mad that they have wept till now.
>
>   **1619** Fletcher *Mons. Thomas* i. iii, ― No word of visitation, as ye love me, And for now Ile leave ye.
>
>   **1860** Thirlwall *Rem.* (1877) I. 395 ― Without this, she would have fallen ere now under the blows.
>
>   **1885–94** R. Bridges *Eros. & Psyche* Feb. iv, ― She is not hence by now six miles at most.
>
> **b.** ***from now (forth, forthward, forward***).
>
> - **A. 1300** *Cursor M.* 3758 ― In dew and gress sere o þorth Sal be þi blissing fra no forth.
>
>   **A. 1300** *Cursor M.* 10976 ― Þou sal be dumb fra nu, Til þat he be born.
>
>   **C. 1400** *Hampole’s Wks.* I. 221 ― And þou sall lufe gastely ilk a mane, and flee fra now forthwarde to lufe fleschly.
>
>   **1503** *Surtees Misc.* (1890) 30 ― John Mitteley & his heires frome now forthe shall wall up··the utter west syde of his swynstye.
>
>   **1855** Kingsley *Westw. Ho!* xvi, ― I could live very well from now till Doomsday without [etc.].
>
>   **1890** *Spectator* 10 May 651/2 ― The Gladstonians could talk with ease on one line of one clause from now till Christmas.
>
> **14.** **a.** As *sb.* The present time. Also *Comb.*
>
> > Gower uses *time* *now* in the same sense.
>
> - **1390** Gower *Conf.* I. 32 ― To peise now with that beforn, The chaf is take for the corn.
>
>   **1390** Gower *Conf.* III. 346 ― Ensamples thou hast many on Of now and ek of time gon.
>
>   **1549** Strype *Eccl. Mem.* 431 ― The tyme is tourned: then was then and now is now.
>
>   **1607** Shaks. *Timon* ii. ii. 152 ― Though you heare now (too late), yet nowes a time.
>
>   **1631** *Celestina* vii. 97 ― Now is now, and then is then; when time serves, we will follow your counsell.
>
>   **1655** Fuller *Serm.* 29 ― Now is an atome, it will puzzle the skill of an angell to divide.
>
>   **1854** Patmore *Angel in Ho.* i. ii. x, ― Where Now and Then are no more twain.
>
>   **1861** Angus *Serm.* 43 ― Base and profligate now-wasters.
>
>   **1861** Angus *Serm.* 44 ― It is only a make-believe of happiness which does not dwell in now.
>
> **b.** So with *the* or *this*.
>
> - **1633** Ford *Broken Hrt.* iv. i, ― Now, uncle, now; this Now is now too late.
>
>   **1685** Dryden *Threnodia* 28 ― With scarce a breathing space betwixt, This now becalmed, and perishing the next.
>
>   **1713** Rowe *Jane Shore* iii, ― This present now Some matters of the State detain our leisure.
>
>   **1771** Wesley *Wks.* (1872) V. 392 ― Enjoy the very, very now, by enjoying Him ‘whose years fail not’.
>
>   **1820** Scott *Monast.* xxxii, ― It must be done this very *now*; or it may never be done.
>
>   **1851** Brimley *Ess.* 183 ― Plant the great hereafter in the now.
>
> **15.** **a.** A present point or moment of time.
>
> - **1630** Drumm. of Hawth. *Flowers of Sion* Poems (1856) 179 ― Still is the same thy Day and Yesterday An undivided Now.
>
>   **1692** Dryden *Eleonora* 306 ― We can scarcely say she died; For but a now did heaven and earth divide.
>
>   **1751** Harris *Hermes* Wks. (1841) 146 ― If a point or now were extended, each of them would contain within itself infinite··other nows.
>
>   **1801** Southey *Thalaba* i. xxviii, ― Time is not here, nor days, nor months, nor years, An everlasting now of solitude!
>
>   **1870** Emerson *Soc. & Solit.* Wks. (Bohn) III. 71 ― An everlasting Now reigns in nature.
>
> **b.** With possessive pronouns.
>
> - **A. 1668** Sir W. Waller *Div. Medit.* (1839) 146 ― In this my day, or rather in this my now.
>
>   **A. 1711** Ken *Preparatives* Poet. Wks. 1721 IV. 7, ― I oft made solemn vows To consecrate to God my Nows.
>
>   **C. 1859** Lowell *Ode to Happiness* 49 ― Man ever with his Now at strife.

I am unconvinced that the OED believes that the uses with prepositions count as adverbs; after all, why then did it group sense 13 with the substantive uses of senses 14 and 15?  But in any event, *now* is quite clearly able to function as a noun, as primary sense 14 and 15 prove.

### *¿Y en castellano?*

Now that that’s out of the way, I must note that even *El Diccionario de la Real Academia Española* [hedges its bets on *ahora*](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=ahora), calling it in places a “locative adverb” rather than merely an adverb.  It includes this example:

> *Por ahora,* su salude se resiste.

There it means *for now*, as in “For now, his health is holding.”  There it specifically calls *ahora* not an adverb but a locative adverb — whatever that means.  Apparently it is something that can function as the object of a preposition.

The RAE does actually provide the example of *Hasta ahora*, but there it just calls the whole thing an *expresión usada* — a set phrase, and does not attempt further deconstruction.

Spanish is considerably less flexible about parts of speech than is English.  You must work rather hard to find instances of plural inflections of words like *ahora* or *ayer* — although these can be found if you look hard enough:

- Some nows: [algunas ahoras](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22algunas+ahoras%22&btnG=Search&client=opera&rls=en&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest&hl=en&nfpr=1&spell=)
- Some yesterdays  [algunos ayeres](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22algunos+ayres%22&client=opera&rls=en&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest&hl=en&nfpr=1&spell=1&sa=X&as_q=&ei=snLzU5q5HsTQiwKUjIHgBg&ved=0CBEQBSgA), [algunas ayeres](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22algunas+ayeres%22&btnG=Search&client=opera&rls=en&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest&hl=en&nfpr=1&spell=)

So sometimes these words do get nouned even in Spanish, or else you couldn’t find them in the plural. (I’ve left out *algunas mañanas*, since that can mean *some mornings* not just *some tomorrows*.  I’ve also left out *algunos hoyes* for *some todays* because I believe all examples I found on the internet to be catachrestic for *algunos días*, which as a phrase is wholly unremarkable.)

The imputed gender for *ahora* is clearly derived from *la hora*, but as you see, people aren’t sure what gender to assign *ayer* when they convert it into  noun, since nouns ending in *‑r* can come in either flavor.  So both *algunos* and *algunas* can be found prefixing the now-plural noun *ayeres* in the wild. Barely.

Fortunately for English, we have no possibility of such confusion of gender with all our yesterdays — nor with our tomorrows for that matter, as Lady Macbeth famously proves when she uses each not just as nouns but indeed even as subjects of verbs:

> **To-morrow, and to-morrow, and to-morrow**,
>   Creeps in this petty pace from day to day,
>   To the last syllable of recorded time;
>   And **all our yesterdays** have lighted fools
>   The way to dusty death. Out, out, brief candle!
>   Life's but a walking shadow, a poor player,
>   That struts and frets his hour upon the stage,
>   And then is heard no more. It is a tale
>   Told by an idiot, full of sound and fury,
>   Signifying nothing.

---

### On Deixis

Words like *here*, *home*, and *now* — words that seem to be both nouns and adverbs — really are in a special category of their very own. They  quite comfortably serve multiple possible “duties” in English sentences, sometimes acting more like a noun, at other times acting more like an adverb, and frequently acting like both.

If you want to further research the literature for this particular sort of dual-lived words and phrases and what they are doing, you should know that they are called [***deictics***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deixis), and what they’re doing is called ***deixis***.

Amongst other things, deictics can include both locative (place) and temporal (time) deictics.  Locative deictics are “place-words” that answer *where*-questions and include [*here*, *there*, and *yonder*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/111063). Temporal deictics are “place-words” that answer *when*-questions, such as *today, tomorrow, yesterday,* and *now*, as well as longer phrases like *last year* and *the week after next*.

Comment: I was hoping you'd weigh in. :) I must run now, but I look forward to reading your tome!

Comment: As you say, *now* is the same as *tomorrow* - or *weekdays* in [my "adverb" question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/). Looking at your answers on both these questions I'm getting a certain sense of "Tweedledee/Tweedledum". In both cases the bottom line is *POS depends on "function within context", and dictionaries often only cover the simplest/most common usages*. So arguably this question is really a *duplicate*, rather than just *related* to that earlier one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The more I think about it, the more I think that deictics will forever confuse people until and unless these are taught as being members of a special word-class of their very own.  Trying to fit everything into Donatius’s eight parts of speech is just plain silly.

Comment: It's a bit like if the folk over at [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/) had decided that every foodstuff must be categorised as *starter, main course, dessert*. You get problems because some components can perform multiple roles, and even more problems because no-one could ever come up with a definitive list of unambiguously distinguishable roles in the first place.

Comment: @tchrist, spot on analysis but for Spanish...when they give the phrasal usages in the DRAE, the parts of speech listed are for the phrase as a whole normally.  So *por ahora* is considered, collectively, a *locución adverbial* (I think you misread *loc.* as locative; they abbreviate a bit much IMO).  Off the top of my head, both adverbs of location and of time are permitted because, as the RAE notes in the Gramática, when you say "ahora" or "aquí", you're saying "en este momento" or "en este lugar", and there's nothing *per se* incorrect (if uncommon) with "por en este lugar".

Comment: @guifa Ah right, yes, I always forget to check tool tips. I knew it meant a set phrase, but misexpanded it in my mind. I’ll fix up the post in a bit.

Answer (score -3):

Let's start with Merriam-Webster Dictionary, which uses "up to now" as an example of "now" being used as a noun.

> now  noun : the present time or moment (been ill up to now)
>   http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/now

It may be easier if you think of your example with slightly different words.  For instance:

Up until now no one has volunteered.
Up to now no one has volunteered.

"Now" is being used an object of the preposition (of the preposition "until" in the example I provided and of the preposition "to" in the example you provided).  Objects of prepositions are always nouns (except if they are pronounds, gerunds, or clauses acting as nouns, but a single word can't be a clause or anything requiring multiple words, so that only leaves a noun/pronoun).  Easy enough, sort of.

What makes your example a little hard to grasp is that "up" is being used as an adverb.

Again an example from Merriam-Webster Dictionary

> up  adverb  3
>    e: in a continual sequence :  in continuance from a point or to a
>   point (from third grade up) (at prices of $10 and up) (up until now)
>   http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up

Based on your comment below it seems hard for you to understand how "up" is being used as an adverb, so I'll add a bit here.  Consider other words that are definitely adverbs.  For instance, "Sadly until now no one has volunteered."  In this case you can definitely see that "sadly" is an adverb, right?  Or "Suspiciously until now no one has volunteered."  Or "Unbelievably until now no one has volunteered." Basically put in whatever adverb you want that might apply and it should help you to see how "up" is being used as an adverb.

Please note since you mentioned an example using "until" that "until" can be a bit confusing.  While it CAN be used as a conjunction in some cases, it CAN also be used as a preposition, especially after the word "up"!  You specifically use "until tomorrow" but that is another prepositional phrase and "tomorrow" is again a noun.

> See definition #3 ("onward to or till (a specified time or
>   occurrence): 'She worked until 6 p.m.'"
>   http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/until?s=t

So your example where the word following until may be an adverb is only true if "until" is used as a conjunction, not if it is used as a preposition, and if the word following "until" is a specific time like "tomorrow" or "6pm" then "until" will always be a preposition and the object of that preposition will always be a noun!

Comment: `"up" is being used as an adverb, modifying "volunteered".` -- Are you sure about that?  "Up to now..." is a common phrase, and has nothing to do with "volunteered".  I wonder if you're thinking of "No one has volunteered up (signed up)?"  That would be an awkward usage of 'volunteered' (to my ears anyway), but wouldn't change the "up to now" part... ("Up to now no one has volunteered(signed) up")

Comment: Further, would that mean that "until" always takes a noun? That might make sense on the surface, but doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: If you look at this dicationary entry for "up" you will see all the examples of "up to" occur only when "up" is being used as an adverb.  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/up?s=t  Just search for "up to".  Also, I made a couple of slight adjustments to my answer which I hope will make it more clear.

Comment: Ugh, my head hurts now. I still don't see how "up" modifies "volunteered" but I guess I can ask that as a separate question.

Comment: I modified my answer again to give you more clarity in understanding how "up" is being used as an adverb.  I hope it's now more clear!

Comment: @Brillig, In the example, *to* is itself the object of the preposition *up*. One of the most common complements for a preposition is another preposition. I mention this because a major, and imo the best, contender for the categorial status of *now* is *preposition*.

Comment: Yes, that is more clear. I see the point you are making now... although I'm not certain it's a valid point. "Willingly has volunteered" makes sense. "Up has volunteered" doesn't... I don't think "Up" is serving the same role that the other adverbs do in your other examples.

Comment: Araucaria this is the same link as above:  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/up?s=t.  See the examples given of "up" being used as an adverb, including "to climb up to the top of a ladder" and "to follow a stream up to its source."  So, you see that "to" is NOT the object of the preposition "up".

Comment: Flimzy not all adverbs are logically interchangeable in all situations so the fact that you can't logically interchange those two in that situation doesn't really show anything.  See my examples in my comment above that show "up" used as an adverb, and I've provided several examples of adverbs that "up" can be switched with in "up to now".

Comment: Say the example "to follow a stream up to its source" with "up" as an adverb per the dictionary example.  That's "up to follow" like "up has volunteered"  Both don't sound all that great in that form.  A little better is "to follow up" and "has volunteered up" and again a little clanky (except the idiom "follow up" happens to be well-used, but in all fairness so is "sign up" which is about the same as "volunteered up").