# "Where is the cat?" - What part of speech is the word "where"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

In the sentence, "Where is the cat?", what part of speech is the word "where"?

Comment: Frankly, I think no one knows.  You can argue it's an adverb, you can argue that it's a conjunction, you can argue that it's a noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Where" is an adverb telling us 'at what location.'

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia uses interrogative word or simply question-word. This word class is not contained in the traditional list of word classes.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative_word

Comment: From that, I guess it would be an "interrogative pro-adverb."

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81: or maybe more of an "interrogative pro-prepositional phrase". Relevant: [Is “now” a “preposition”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/291007)

Answer (score -1):

The term is called a [locative](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/locative), since it orients you at a **location**.

Comment: This would be better if you included a linked dictionary definition of locative.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Locative is not a part of speech, but rather _words or phrases expressing location_. For example, _in the yard_ is a prepositional phrase with a locative role in _We stopped in the yard_.