# Adverbs of location after be verb

Tags: syntactic-analysis, copular-verbs, adverbials, locatives

> We're **upstairs**.

In this sentence, is *upstairs* a noun or an adverb? I think it's the latter because if it was a noun, the sentence is missing a preposition before *upstairs*. To my knowledge, in a SVC sentence, only nouns or adjectives can be a complement. Are adverbs of location, or locatives, exceptions to this rule?

Comment: Trad grammar treats it as an adverb, modern grammar as a preposition.

Comment: I'm confused. So is it both correct to say you don't need a preposition before *upstairs* because it's an adverb and it's an exception, AND to say that you don't need a preposition in the sentence because *upstairs* is already a preposition, depending on how you'd look at it?

Comment: Related: [What part of speech does “here” have in “I am here”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111058)

Comment: Some modern grammars treat it as a preposition, but most don't. It's a location, which is usually a noun; in this case it's a predicate noun. But the fact that it's locative is more important than its POS, which is irrelevant anyway, since English words can assume practically any POS.

Comment: @John Lawler Could you _please_ give the names of some modern grammars that dispute the vaunted infallibility some ascribe to CGEL on this issue?

Comment: I never comment on religious matters.

Answer (score 1):

Given that "upstairs" is a compound derived from the preposition *up* and the noun *stairs,* it seems most likely that it will act like a one-word prepositional phrase. For example, we can use the adverb *right* before it ("They are right upstairs"). Some linguists classify words that behave this way as prepositions (specifically, "intransitive prepositions"; for analyses and discussion, see [Is "now" a "preposition"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/291007)).

If you accept that classification, then the use of "upstairs" as a predicative complement is not exceptional behavior. Prepositional phrases can clearly be predicative complements, as in the sentences "They are **in the house**" or "They are **on the bus**."

If you don't accept that classification, then I guess you do have to say that "adverbs of location" or whatever you call words like *upstairs, downstairs, indoors, outside...* (as well as "particles" like *in, out, up*) can be predicative complements.

Comment: prepositional phrases without prepositions work like nouns, since prepositions are mostly used to mark nouns and many constructions treat PPs like nouns anyway.

Answer (score -1):

How about **"We're home."**? In your sentence, **"We're upstairs."**, the word *upstairs* is used as an adverb. See [upstairs](https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=upstairs%20meaning&oq=upstairs&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.5324j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) in google dictionary for more.

Comment: "I'm home." is the exact sentence that I came up with when I was told adverbs cannot act as a complement. But if you think, "I'm quickly," it's not grammatically correct at all. So in general, you would think most adverbs are not accepted as a complement. Hence my question: Are adverbs of location exception to the rule? Is it correct if I say adverbs of location can act as a complement, and they're one of the exceptions to nouns and adjectives being only forms of a complement? Or is it a complete false statement that only nouns and adjectives can be used as complements?

Comment: Notice that "quickly" is an adverb that is only used to express the extent of  an action verb used; however, in "I'm quickly.", 'am' is a 'be'-verb which is not an action verb hence you cannot use adverbs of action-verbs with those which are not  action verbs

Comment: Also, 'be'-verbs tells the state / status of the topic / subject.