# Usage of "go to" vs "go"

Tags: word-choice, grammar, rules

I'm trying to explain the difference between "go to" and "go" and I'm not sure what the actual rule is. I've tried searching about it, but I couldn't find anything.

When should I use "go to" and when should I use "go?" For example, I should say "Let's go home" but not "Let's go to home." On the flip side, "Let's go to your house," but not "Let's go your house."

Can someone help me with the rule behind this?

Comment: _Home_ is about the only one that doesn't need _to_, but there is a small set of locative words that don't need determiners (_the, a, his, some, most_): _go to -∅- work/school/church/college/university_ (in the UK, also _hospital_), but _go to my job/the store/a play/Bill's party_

Comment: In this example, *home* is an adverb.  One doesn't go *to* adverbs.

Comment: @user61979 According to [John Lawler](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111426/can-an-adverb-be-a-noun-at-the-same-time), 'It's an adverbial prepositional phrase that has been stripped of its prepositions and determiners, leaving only a naked noun to stand for the whole phrase. [(]That's how a noun can be used as an adverb.[)]'

Comment: You can also *go halves, go places, go yesterday, go today, go tomorrow, go bananas, go commando, go scat, go hippie, go country, go native, go stag, go bush, go ape, go fishing, go walkabout, go bust, go all the way*, or *go eyes wide open*.  Well, or *go Dutch*, but that doesn’t quite count.

Comment: @tchrist But most of those things represent a state of mind, and follow the form "to go mad"; which I would have thought of as a composite verb. Perhaps the same thing as a verb + adverb?

Comment: "go home" is an idiom, There is no rule. You just have to memorize it.

Comment: Also related: [Is there a reason the British omit the article when they 'go to hospital'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/is-there-a-reason-the-british-omit-the-article-when-they-go-to-hospital).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is this sentence wrong? "He went to home."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233564/why-is-this-sentence-wrong-he-went-to-home)

Comment: Related: [Why does CGEL call "home", "abroad", "here", and "there" prepositions instead of adverbs like dictionaries say?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/547159/).

Comment: @tchrist You can also big as an alternative to going home.

Answer (score 2):

- **Go to** *can't* be used with:

  1. home
  2. downtown
  3. west / east / north / south
  4. outside / inside
  5. there / back
- **Go to** is used with **noun,** that means uncommon places (not the cinema, not a restaurant...):

  ```
  go to school / university 
  go to prison / church
  got to work / bed
  ```
- **Go on** is used with places related to holidays:

  1. vacation / honeymoon
  2. trip / cruise
- **Go for a** is used с **noun** related to activities:

  ```
  go for a swim / run / walk 
  go for a beer / massage
  ```
- **Go + verb:**

  ```
  1. Let's go eat.
  2. I need to go wash my car.
  3. Go clean your room!
  ```
- **Go + gerund:**
  When we are talking about hobbies or entertaining activities.

  ```
  go hiking
  go shopping

  going swimming

  went sightseeing
  ```

Comment: "Go on " is used for more than holidays. "Let's go on a a gruelling 25 mile assault course." I think "go to" is used for nouns that are places or static events ("go to a wedding") and "go on" for nouns that are travels in some sense. Also you do "go to" a cinema.

Comment: Thank you for your additions.

Answer (score 0):

What do you notice that is different between your examples?

> Let's go home.
>
> Let's go to your house.

Allow me to give a different example:

> Let's go to your home.

Are you seeing it?  It's the possessive your.  What happens when you throw that possessive in?  Home goes from being an adverb (modifying go), to a noun which forms a part of an [adverbial prepositional phrase](http://www.infoplease.com/cig/grammar-style/prepositional-phrases-big-daddy-phrases.html).  (I don't believe it fits the definition of the indirect object the going is not happening to the house, but rather toward it.  Perhaps I'm wrong here.)

Home is a rare word that forms an adverb in this form.

On its own, *your home* isn't typically used as an adverbial phrase to modify go.  Instead we make it part of the prepositional phrase *to your home* because it explains the action of going.

Comment: He can’t hear you. You can only reach his inbox if you name him in a comment chain that he himself is already part of, or which is affixed to one of his own postings. So you could only ask him in the original question’s chain, in this case.

Comment: @tchrist Gotcha.  Thanks.  I was sort of hoping he was going to read down after his comment, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Some special cases:

- go home
- go here
- go there

Use **go** with directions

- go in/inside
- go up
- go aft
- go downtown<sup>1</sup>

Use **go to** with places or static events

- go to school
- go to the cinema
- go to a wedding

The question of when you use the definite/indefinite/no article is separate and covered in other questions.

Use **go on** with journeys

- go on a cruise
- go on a hike
- go on an expedition
- go on a vacation

There are other questions covering whether you go *on* or *in* modes of transport, and other combinations with "go".

Notes:

1. "Downtown" and similar can be both places and directions, so you "go downtown" but you "go to downtown New York"