# What is “long” doing in “all (time-period) long”?

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis, adverbs, time, measure-phrases

What part of speech is ***long*** playing the part of in the bold parts of the quotations below?

- For one thing, it shows at a glance how much money is on hand for any particular  purpose **all month long**.
- The fishermen stayed in their nets **the whole night long**.
- Some people prefer to live in places that have the same weather  or climate **all year long**.
- He had told them to sit on the edge of the sandbox **all recess long** and not move  a finger.
- Wild animals, driven by hunger, came **all winter long** to live close to the feeding  station.
- Other friends worked hard **all semester long** and didn't feel any pressure at all as  the final exam approached.
- One half of the labor actually expended in the cultivation of these grapes would  have kept them in tip-top order **the whole season long** if they had been planted in  four rows as already suggested rather than in twenty short ones.
- It suddenly came to him that he would never, **his whole life long**, see Gramps  again.
- He did such good work, and so much, that nobody would question him. Plus he  could go **all shift long**, and most of them couldn't.
- She realized suddenly how old and hurt he was, an elder with gray hair and  loose skin, and yet he had been working with his paddle **nearly the whole day long**.
- **All year long**, **all decade long**, **all century long**, the sun just keeps on  shining.

To me it looks like it’s acting as some sort of “adverbial *post*position of time”, just as ***during*** is an adverbial *pre*position of time in phrases like *during the night*.

The problem is that ***long*** follows its NP complement, just as ***ago*** does in *three years ago*, making it more of a postposition like *ago* than a preposition like *during*.  I think.

How should this sort of construction best be classified? The OED calls ***long*** an adverb here.

---

## Edit

My confusion may be that I’m unclear about the transition from something being a modifier that takes a complement and it becoming an actual preposition/postposition/adposition.

I am not referring to ***long*** used as an adverb in such collocations as “How long have you been here?” or “as long as you like”.  Rather, I mean what the OED gives as its sense 6 of [***long***<sup>1</sup> *adv.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/109979) the following:

> **6**. Subjoined to expressions designating a period of time, with the sense: Throughout the length of (the period specified).  [Compare German *sein leben lang*.]

It’s been used this way at least since Middle English; the first citation given is for “all year long” from back around 1290 ᴀᴅ in the *South English Legendary* (a source that provides [2359 quotations](http://www.oed.com/view/source/w111)):

> - *c*1290      [*S. Eng. Leg.*](http://www.oed.com/view/source/w111) I. 264/122 
>     Heore ȝat was swiþe faste i-mad: þoruȝ al þe ȝere longue.

This is not one of the entries that has yet been updated for the *OED3*, so perhaps the analysis has changed since the *OED2*.   However, it is similar to [the entry for  ***ago*** *adj*. and *adv*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/4080), which has indeed been updated for the *OED3*, and which remains an adverb when used in phrases like “long ago” and “longer ago”, but which it classifies as an adjective when used in the more customary collocation of time, as with this recent citation:

> - 2009      S. Craven *Ruthless Awakening* 32  
>    We agreed on the guest lists ages ago.

There appears to be some dispute about whether things like ***ago*** constitute [actual instances of “postpositions” in English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_prepositions#Postpositions), or whether they are better left in their traditional categories of adjectival or adverbial modifiers that just happen to follow their modificand.

I am confortable with saying that [nouns like *home* or *Tuesday* can be used adverbially](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/75510), as in “I’m going home” or “I’ll see you Tuesday”, but this doesn’t quite seem like one of those to me.  On the other hand, it does remind me of:

- I stayed through the whole night.
- I stayed the whole  night through.

If the first is to be called a preposition, but the second is not to be called a postposition, then we have to call *through* an adjective “modifying” *night* and the entire thing somehow a noun phrase being used adverbially.  That seems to be the very sort of classificational contortion as is being attempted with calling ***long*** an adjective, and I find both to be particularly unsatisfying approaches.

---

## SUMMARY

A clearer explanation of what ***long*** is and is not in the type of collocations presented in the initial example list would be  much appreciated. It’s ok if multiple models of analysis are presented.

---

PS: I do not have personal access to the recent work by Dennis Kurzon about adpositions in:

> *Adpositions: Pragmatic, Semantic and Syntactic Perspectives*, ed. by Dennis Kurzon and Silvia Adler. John Benjamins, 2008

Comment: How long? Two hours long. Three days long. A few weeks long. Some years long. His whole life long. Looks to me like everything else modifies *long*, whether it's deployed as an adverb or as an adjective.

Comment: @StoneyB So do you consider “three days ago” as having “three days” modifying “ago”, too?

Comment: But you can't ask *How ago?* I don't recall ever hearing of a *six-month-ago conference*. You can't nominalize to *an agoth [or would it be 'an agait'?] of three days.* You don't say *He worked so ago*.

Comment: And how bout this: *three days ago* ... *long, long ago*. I don't know exactly how to characterize this; but I'm pretty sure *long* doesn't work like *ago* or *since* or *during*.

Comment: *Long* seems similar to *old* as in *3 years old*.

Comment: @StoneyB It’s not the *long* in “long, long ago” that is the question, but rather the one is “all night long” which is.

Comment: I suspect that this is simply the noun phrase version of adjectives like _nightlong, weeklong,_ and _yearlong._

Comment: @BraddSzonye Hm, maybe. “How long is your driveway?” “My driveway is three miles long.” “I have a three-mile–long driveway.”  You could do the same with an adverb.

Comment: The relationship is even clearer with _footlong_; I posted an answer elaborating on that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Old English word *lang* has suffix forms [*-ling*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ling#Old_English) and [*-long,*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-long) (“with the direction, duration, or length”), similar to [-lic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ly) (“with the body or form”) that survives as the very common *-ly* adverbial suffix form.

The *-ling* form, once used in words like *hinderling* (“in the backward direction”) has been supplanted by another usage, the nominal diminutive: *darling, yearling.* The *-long* form still survives, with all three senses, in words like *headlong, nightlong,* and *footlong.*

The suffix is adverbial in directional modifiers like *headlong* and *arselong,* adjectival in metric modifiers like *footlong* and *nightlong.* When combined with a quantifier to form an adjectival or adverbial phrase, the metrics compounds break into their component words:

- I ate a footlong sandwich. [adjective]
- This sandwich is one foot long. [adjectival phrase]
- This sandwich measures one foot long. [adverbial phrase]
- We attended a nightlong party. [adjective]
- We stayed at the party the whole night long. [adverbial phrase]

As these express spatial and temporal *dimension* rather than *relationship,* it's not clear whether these are adpositions or simply adjectives with an idiomatic phrase order. However, the close similarity to *a hole one foot through* or *party the whole night through* suggests that they may indeed be postpositions.

Answer (score 2):

@tchrist: Yes you are right, in all the above examples Long has been used as **adverb**, but as an adverb it's used as following

**Adverb 1.** for a long time

- **How long** have you been waiting ?

**Adverb 2.** a long time before or after a particular time or event

- He retired long before the war.

**Adverb 3.** used after a **noun** to **emphasize** that something happens for the **whole** of a           particular **period** of time

- We had to wait **all day long**.
- They stayed up **the whole night long**.

(information courtesy OALD)

Answer (score 2):

**Long** in *all day long* is like **old** in *3 years old*.

Comment: Follow-up question: The exact same question as before, but with "long" replaced with "old" and the quotes changed accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

All of your examples fit [Merriam-Webster's definition **3b** of *long*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/long) as "having a specified duration:"

> - all month
> - the whole night
> - all recess
> - all winter
> - all semester
> - the whole season
> - his whole life
> - all shift
> - nearly the whole day
> - all year, all decade, all century

In this usage, M-W simply identifies its part of speech as an *adjective*.

Comment: I considered but rejected that, because it produces an invalid parse using any valid production that I can imagine.  To illustrate: In the phrase, "I worked all night long", if both *all* and *long* are adjectives that somehow modify the noun *night*, then what in the world type sentence is this? It then becomes N-V-NP, but it cannot be SVO, since the presumed NP "all night long" is not the object of *work*.

Comment: I believe that your parse is incorrect. "All night" is the <time-duration> in the construct; separating "all" from "night" is like separating "five" from "minutes" in the phrase "five minutes long."

Comment: If I work all day, is day a noun or an adverb?

Comment: Dictionaries tend to identify "all day long" and its brethren as _phrases_; however, you seem to be dissatisfied with simply tossing them off as _adverbial phrases_. [This grammarian](http://books.google.com/books?id=oNoNAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq=intext:%22all+day+long%22+intext:%22adverbial+phrase%22&source=bl&ots=ykloYhKtrZ&sig=2SZdLUqAMEJ2WsuYY-gmS_GbPDU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mN1uUZODJZDSigLI_oDADg&ved=0CGAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=intext%3A%22all%20day%20long%22%20intext%3A%22adverbial%20phrase%22&f=false) shares your dissatisfaction, and I refer you to him.

Comment: I will probably be able to content myself with some sort of adverbial phrase, whether with or without an adposition.

Answer (score 1):

It's intimating the entirety. "All night long", for example, can be properly stated as "the entire night".

Answer (score 0):

The adverb *long* depicts that :

1. the verb is acting upon the subject/object without a pause/fail. It goes on, regardless of any other happening.
2. since the verb is acting all through the situation of time/any other parameter, it is only the verb in its sense/*league* to be acting upon the subject/object.

Taking the example above,

**The fishermen *stayed in their nets* the whole night long.**

In the example above,

1. the fishermen stayed in the nets throughout the night. They did not get away doing so. None of them got off through it for even a single second. 
   the long describes that staying was the only thing in the league that the fishermen could do while they were at the place they were.
2. since the fishermen stayed in the nets throughout the night, it is the only place where they stayed then. Therefore proving the second point.

Good Luck :)