# Is it possible to use a noun as an adverb? Would that be stupid?

Tags: meaning

I'll create some random examples:

"I'll take the **elevator** to go to the 12th floor."

"I'll take the **lift** to get up there."

Now, let us use the same sentences treating the noun as an adverb:

"I'll go **elevatorly** to the 12th floor."

"I'll get up there **liftly**."

I'm pretty sure that this would be well understood in a trivial context, but **would that be stupid?**

Is there a real example of this in the english language?

A last and more stupid example:

"The witch flew **broomly** through the skies." haha

Comment: I guess it is possible in some cases like Luck:Luckily but your examples seem unacceptable "grammatically"(see what I did there?)

Comment: How would you act the adverb: liftly? Normally if someone were to tell you they went somewhere slowly you could imagine that action and mimic it. So to *open a door slowly*, *to drive a car slowly* are possible variations. How would you utilize "liftly" or "broomly" outside the specific contexts you provided?

Comment: The adverb would be used to change the verb normally, but according to the function of the noun depending on the context. For example "To clean broomly the house." In this context, the function of the broom is not that of a "flying thing".

Comment: [Nouns get used as adverbs all the time.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/75510/2085) They just don’t need a *-ly* to do so.

Comment: I suppose, "To clean broomly" would answer the question *how* you cleaned the house! :)

Comment: Use of the -ly suffix sounds stupid, I'm afraid. Overcompensating. But Zero derivation can work: _I'll go elevator to the 12th floor and escalator the rest of the way._ It's like deleting prepositions; in context, anything predictable can be deleted (or, from the listener's point of view, can be inserted) if it makes sense.

Comment: Yes, this sounds wrong.

Comment: Consider: *“I’ll call you **the day after tomorrow.”*** There you have an NP acting adverbially and without benefit of any sort of preposition or case inflection. It’s easy to do this with time, harder but not always impossible with other relationships. Another easy one is the noun *home*, which slips easily and smoothly into an adverbial role without raising any supercilious eyebrows.

Comment: Perfect examples. "home" is a perfect one. So it becomes stupid when you explicitly turn it into an adverb by adding the -ly suffix. But, in fact, "I'll go homely" has a very different role compared to "I'll go home". In the aforesaid, the "homely" transfer its "function" to the verb in the same way that happened in my examples ("liftly"). Considering that "house" does not have a "function" that can be combined with "to go", it would be nonsense (Perhaps: "I'll shelter myself homely.") haha meaning "I'm going to shelter myself in a home-like way."

Comment: @ Ericson Willians: Note that *homely* (and *friendly, cowardly, kingly, scholarly, monthly*, etc.) are ***adjectives***, not ***adverbs***.

Comment: As a suffix forming adverbs, _-ly_ is used exclusively for adjectives, never nouns—that’s the only thing that really makes your examples not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The suffix *-wise* can be used to transform a noun into an adverb. A classic example is *clockwise*.

Consider this comment in the [Compact OED](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/--wise?q=-wise):

> In modern English the suffix -wise is attached to nouns to form a sentence adverb meaning ‘concerning or with respect to’, as in confidence-wise, tax-wise, price-wise, time-wise, news-wise, and culture-wise. The suffix is very productive and widely used in modern English but most of the words so formed are considered inelegant or not good English style.

A search at [findtheword.info](http://www.findtheword.info/Search.aspx?stype=words-matching-pattern&sword=%2awise&page=8) for **wise* reveals 356 recognized terms, most of which seem to be a strain.

Comment: Also *-fashion* can be used in much the same way. You could (just about) [swim fish-fashion](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22swim+fish-fashion%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example.