# Is There a Way to Remember Nouns, Verbs & Adjectives

Tags: parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis, mnemonic, diagramming

Is there a simple and concise way to remember nouns, adjectives and verbs **aside** from poems?

I am aware of a number of poems available to aid memory, but I am looking for something a lot more simple.

I am also aware that everybody is different and, therefore, some methods will work for some people and not for others, but I am intrigued nonetheless.

**UPDATE:**

As tchrist correctly suggests, a mnemonic is indeed what I am seeking.  Hopefully this clears things up.

Many thanks.

Comment: If you see 'to' directly in front, then it's probably a verb. If you see 'the' or 'a' directly in front it's a noun or adjective. Other than that it's difficult.

Comment: @Mitch Give it to Mitch, he’s a scantily clad verb.

Comment: @Snooker Your question has worded suggests that you want to find a mnemonic device for knowing whether a word is this or that part of speech. However, it has been suggested that you may instead be seeking something more definitional, such as the award-winning [*Schoolhouse Rock* series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoolhouse_Rock) did so marvellously well for schoolchildren. If that is your goal, I commend you to Youtube, where all of the *Schoolhouse Rock* episodes can be enjoyed to your heart’s desire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## *tl;dr*

Words do not have inherent parts of speech in English: it all depends on how they’re used.

---

## Bare Words Can Have No “Part of Speech”

There is no way to “remember” the part of speech of a word in isolation, because there is no such thing.  Grammatical roles in English are fluid things which are assigned based on how a word happens to be used in any particular utterance.

It’s like asking whether *record* is a noun or a verb. In speech, stress may help guide you guide you, and in writing, its function in the phrase will tell you the answer for that particular phrase. But there is no guaranteed way to give any definitive answer for a word denuded of its functioning context.

So it makes no sense to try to “remember” which “part of speech” a word “is”, for all of those scare-quoted terms make far too many tacit assumptions of dubious nature.  Even *part of speech* is open to debate. Are their many or few? If there are few, how to express the different subtypes?

For example, try saying something is an [adverb](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/75510/2085).  Yes ok, but then you notice that some so-called adverbs act completely differently from others, so much so that you would think there would be distinct names for the disparate roles these two so-called “adverbs” are fulfilling in actual speech.

More trivia follows.

---

### Examples of common words with multiple possible part-of-speech assignments

When you ask about a word’s POS in isolation, it is rare for any one answer to be the full, correct, and sufficient answer.  Even words of very strict traditional POS can be readily co-opted into other jobs as need arises.

It’s like asking:

- whether *an* is an article, a verb, or an archaic conjunction
- whether *record* is a noun or a verb
- whether *awake* is a verb or a predicate adjective
- whether *cool* is a noun, a verb, an adjective, an adverb, or an interjection
- whether *mine* is a noun, a verb, a possessive pronoun, or an archaic possessive adjective
- whether *set* is a noun, a verb, or an adjective (or historically, even a whilom conjunction!)
- whether *inside* is a noun, an adverb, or a preposition
- whether *dog* is a noun, a verb, or an attributive noun used adjectivally
- whether *contra* a noun, an adverb, or a preposition
- whether *home* is a noun, a verb, an adverb, or a locative noun used adverbially
- whether *once* is a noun, a conjunctive, an adjective, or an adverb
- whether *that* is a conjunction, a relative pronoun, a demonstrative pronoun, or a demonstrative adjective
- whether *adieu* is a noun, a verb, and adverb, or an interjection — or some sort of unclassifiable foreign term
- whether *minus* is a noun, a preposition, an adverb, or and adjective
- whether *read* is a noun, a verb, or a participial adjective
- whether *crap* is a noun, a verb, an adjective, or an interjection
- or whether *running* is a (de)verbal noun, a verb, a participial adjective, or an adverb.

Those questions are all unanswerable when the nude words stand alone.  Only when they participate in one or another grammatical construction do they at that point take up the role there assigned to them for that nonce-use.  Tomorrow they shall play a different role altogether.

### Just how many parts of speech *are* there?

Even when you start to assign parts of speech (POS) to words in utterances, your working set of possible POS tags is itself open to broad debate.  The [*Art of Grammar* “Techne Grammatike”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_of_Grammar) that served the classical community had a mere 8 possible POS tags: **nouns, pronouns, verbs, participles, adverbs, prepositions, interjections,** and **conjunctions**. This quickly proved inadequate as **articles** began to be used in Latin, but it look nearly another millennium still for **adjectives** to merit their own POS tag.

POS assignment is one of the first steps in syntactic analysis, but cannot be separated from it.  You have to grok the syntax before you can assign a word its POS tag. Depending on the language being analysed, and depending on the goal of the analysis, today you will see [many, many, many POS tags used “in the wild”](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/75510).  Depending on your purpose, any or even all of these might well apply — and that is to English alone!

Of these, many of the subtypes within the first six categories are **subject to morphological inflection** under the rules of inflectional morphology that govern that particular classification.  You can inflect nouns by number, pronouns by case, demonstrative determiners by number (*this, these, that, those*), verbs by tense and number and person, and adjectives and adverbs by degree.

- nouns

  - attributive nouns
  - possessive nouns
  - count nouns
  - deverbal nouns
  - mass nouns
  - proper nouns
  - compound nouns
  - vocative nouns (also known as nouns of direct address)
- pronouns

  - disjunctive pronouns
  - dummy pronouns
  - impersonal pronouns
  - indefinite pronouns
  - intensive pronouns
  - interrogative pronoun
  - personal pronouns
  - reciprocal pronouns
  - reflexive pronouns
- verbs

  - auxiliary verbs
  - copular or linking verbs
  - coverbs
  - defective verbs
  - finite verbs
  - impersonal verbs
  - intransitive verbs
  - modal verbs
  - non-finite verbs
  - preverbs
  - pro-verbs
  - transitive verbs
  - bitransitive verbs
- determiners

  - articles
  - interrogative possessive determiners
  - demonstrative determiners
  - deictic demonstratives
  - quantifiers
  - multal quantifiers
  - paucal quantifiers
  - pre-modifiers
  - numbers
  - cardinal numbers
  - ordinal numbers
  - measure words
- adjectives

  - compound adjectives
  - demonstrative adjectives
  - interrogative particles
  - nominalized adjectives
  - participial adjectives
  - possessive adjectives
  - predicative adjectives
  - proper adjectives
  - absolute superlative
- adverbs

  - adverbs of manner
  - adverbs of place
  - adverbs of time
  - adverbs of degree
  - anomalous/miscellanous/other adverbs
  - pro-adverb
  - deictic adverbs
- adpositions

  - circumpositions
  - postpositions
  - prepositions
- conjunctions

  - conjunctive adverbs
  - coordinating conjunctions
  - corellative conjunctions
  - subordinating conjunctions
- clitics

  - proclitics
  - enclitics
  - endoclitics
  - mesoclitics
- contractions
- particles
- interjections
- fillers
- foreign words

If that seems like too many to remember, it probably is. For most people.  But then again, most people don’t have any need to know a word’s “part of speech” anyway.  It makes very little difference, if any, in normal communication.  Notice how in this [Wikipedia example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech#English), words do whatever you need them to do:

> In certain circumstances, even words with primarily grammatical functions can be used as verbs or nouns, as in “We must look to the *how*’s and not just the *why*’s” or “Miranda was *to*-ing and *fro*-ing and not paying attention”.

Those simple examples should definitively put to rest the “part-of-speech question” as being at best meaningless in isolation and at worst misleading and wrong.

It really is of very little to no use at all in almost any real-world situation — and I do not count automated syntactic analysis, natural language processing, and computational linguistics, fascinating topics though they can certainly be in an academic context, as having much to do with real-world situations.

Comment: I've always been interested in classifications, and this is a good one, pretty much what I learned and use as a grammarian. But it's got more detail than one needs, at first; later on it's a good list to have, though the bullet points never format right for sublists, I've found.  The main point, though, is that naming word classes is only useful if you understand what each class **does** in grammar and can use them to put together constituents. **Constituents** are what English grammar is about; not words.

Comment: +1 @JohnLawler: How about dependency grammar v. constituency grammar? What is the status of either with respect to the other?

Comment: They're not competitive, really, except for those in competition. Dependency grammars of various sorts are good ways to describe grammatical relations (Su, DO, IO, oblique), which depend on the predicate; a good example is Arc Pair Grammar. Constituents are important, though, because it's turned out that all syntactic movement, deletion, and copying phenomena apply only to constituents. So that's a crucial thing to determine. Generally, one needs both to give a decent account. Most theories are too tied up with the glories of mathematics, and too little concerned with real phenomena.

Comment: @JohnLawler I’ve spruced up the sublists, rearranged the sections a bit to front-load the payload, fixed (some of) the typos, and relegated the tedious trivia to down below the eyes-glaze-over cut-line.  Please feel free to edit in anything substantial that I’ve omitted which you feel would help future readers who chance upon this answer.

Comment: @JohnLawler: All right, that sounds fair.

Comment: @tchrist: OK, except we're on hold and will probably close because of question defects, so this answer is unlikely to survive long. That's the fate of information, after all.

Comment: I've just found this, and it seems a good answer to my firstish question on ELU.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/616793/2085).