# Proper placement of "exactly"?

Tags: adverbs, adverb-position

I want to ask a question whose meaning is "what is the exact way in which X works?". Where is the most appropriate place for the adverb "exactly"?

- How *exactly* does X work?
- How does *exactly* X work?
- How does X *exactly* work?
- How does X work *exactly*?

Comment: Adverbs modify the verb, they can precede or follow the verb. In that case, sentences No3 and 4, which mean the same, probably fit best, although No1 is also grammatical.

Comment: Errata corrige; adverbs modify all types of words, not only verbs, I was making a generalization. Something you don't do on EL&U.

Answer (score 1):

None, in my opinion, for the meaning you provided.

- (How *exactly*) does X work? = What is the precision of X? (compare: How *loudly* can this speaker play?)
- How does (*exactly* X) work? = Why is precisely X effective, but if you modify X by a small detail it stops working? (compare: Why do we have *exactly* thirty-two teeth?)
- ?How does X *exactly* work? - I do not think this would be correct, but I'm willing to be proven wrong.
- How does X (work *exactly*)? = What is the mechanism by which X is given the ability to be exact? (compare: How do you close that door *quietly*? I've never managed it...)

And the two (three?) correct ones:

- How, *exactly*, does X work? = What is the exact mechanism by which X works?
- How does X work, *exactly*? - Same
- *Exactly* how does X work? - Not 100% sure about this one, but I'll go out on a limb and say I find it's fine

Of course, eliding the commas is common, so I'd vote the first and the fourth of your examples as the closest ones.

The reason I have trouble with the third one is the fact that "exactly", while undoubtedly an adverb, does not modify "work". It makes no sense for it to modify "work". The paraphrase for the original question would likely be "Please explain to me exactly how X works", and in this paraphrase it is clear that "exactly" modifies "explain". The fact that "Please explain to me" has been elided in the sentence *while keeping the same meaning* should not suddenly be able to shift the attachment of this adverb. This goes well with the fact (at least fact in the way I perceive it) that "exactly" is kept apart from the sentence by the commas.

Also, pet peeve: I hate the word "adverb". It is useless and misleading. Adverbs are modifiers that are not nouns or adjectives. They can certainly modify things that are not verbs, such as other adverbs ("*very* quickly"), adjectives ("*reasonably* pretty")...

Comment: You might enjoy reading this question [What exactly is an “adverb”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/what-exactly-is-an-adverb/75510#75510)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Indeed I did, thank you.

Comment: I think what you say about the first variant is splitting hairs. /haʊ ɪɡˈzækli/ is an extremely common question in the meaning "what is the exact way" and virtually *unheard of* with the meaning "what is the precision". For all intents and purposes, it is a fixed phrase. So when you write it down, people will take it to mean the former give or take any amount of commas. In fact if you tell them you really intended the latter meaning and they misunderstood you, they will likely shrug and put the blame on you, telling you to reword because you're being weird.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I somewhat agree that the word exactly has very limited use in common parlance of the meaning "precision" but it's a legitimate usage.

Answer (score 0):

The addition of parenthetical commas, like so:

> How, exactly, does X work?

is the only correct way to convey the intended meaning, without ambiguity.

Comment: The placement here is important because if the phrase is being spoken then there's no way to convey the placement of commas.

Comment: @franklin Oh yes, we do "pronounce" commas in speech, through a pause, and a change in tone. Say it aloud and try. :)

Answer (score 0):

As Amadan pointed out, all four are grammatically correct, assuming for the second example that X is ambiguous or inexact, requiring or at least benefitting from the specification "exact."

I don't see the desired meaning in the question; the question is more difficult when considered for only the generic case.